# What is the difference between \subfigure and \subfloat?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I've been just reading through this [Latex wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) and I spotted they advocate use of `\subfloat` in figures. I've always used `\subfigure`.
What is the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`\subfigure` belongs to the obsolete package with the name `subfigure`. It's still supported in the newer `subfig` package because of backward compatibility. I recommend to use `\subfloat`.

`subfig` should be preferref to `subfigure`, that's why the command `\subfigure` is not needed. Though it's available if you load the configuration `altsf.cfg`. It defines simply

```
\@ifundefined{c@subfigure}{\newsubfloat{figure}}{}
\def\subfigure{\subfloat}
\@ifundefined{c@subtable}{\newsubfloat{table}}{}
\def\subtable{\subfloat}
```

and further options for captions.

Comment: I remember seeing some discussion about subfigure not being obsolete and `subfig` no maintainer. Anyone has further details on this?

Comment: Vafa Khalighi is the new mainainer of `subfig`.

Comment: @Leo: From the abstract of the subfig documentation: "The `subfig` package ... replaces the older `subfigure` package."

Answer (score 5):

Note that you might prefer `subfig` to `subfloat` if wanting to use `tocloft` (*) to configure your TOC, LOF and LOT look and feel.

In which case, for example,

```
\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}
  {\usepackage[subfigure,...]{tocloft}}
  {\usepackage[...]{tocloft}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{...}
...
\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}{\renewcommand{\cftsubfigpresnum}{...}}{}
...
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{...}
...
\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}{\renewcommand{\cftsubfigpagefont}{...}}{}
```

(*) I'm sure `tocloft`'s [Current Maintainer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson) could provide the canonicals should anyone want to ask.

Comment: Err, just because I'm the maintainer doesn't mean I always know stuff like this `:)` I took over the package for continuity, not because I know its internals inside out!

Comment: Ha ha, Will, I know you're cleverer by far! :))