# How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?

Tags: packages, best-practices, obsolete

I'm an on and off user of LaTeX so I'm not familiar with every package out there. Having said that, whenever I use LaTeX and need to accomplish a certain goal (i.e. [generate a list of appendices](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2233)), I search around and find some kind of solution that involves a package that I didn't know about. I think that's great, I learn something new, and it goes in my template file.

Every now and then, though, my search comes up with a package that, after much wrangling, I find out that it's obsolete. An example of this is just recently I came across the subfigure package and wanted to try it out. Soon after I found out from here that it has become [superseded by the subfig package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/what-is-the-difference-between-subfigure-and-subfloat/1968#1968). I usually keep my TeX up-to-date because I like keeping up with new XeLaTeX features.

My question is, is there a map or timeline of what TeX packages should be avoided because there are better ways of doing things? An idea I have is some kind of list of all packages split by what they accomplish, then cancelling out packages whose features are incorporated into and improved upon by newer packages.

Edit: another example is lscape versus pdflscape. The latter implements rotating pages in the final PDF not just for pdftex but also for other drivers such as xetex. The only way I found out about this was Googling *latex lscape rotate xelatex*, for which the second link leads to the [pdflscape texdoc](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pdflscape.pdf) (PDF).

Great answers so far. I'll check them out and see which one works best for me.

Edit 2: Turns out that my question is a bit of a dupe in the sense that a great answer came up on an unrelated question. The nag package [apparently consults l2tabu and checks your document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/589#589). Gotta try it!

Comment: Aye, nag is good package!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<s>Actually [subfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) isn't maintained anymore.</s> I would use packages like »subcaption« (shipped with [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)) or [floatrow](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow). A good list of obsolete packages and other outdated stuff can be found in [l2tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu).

Comment: "A good list of obsolete packages ... can be found in l2tabu.", which was last updated 2007.

Comment: The German version of this document is from 5 August 2010.

Comment: This is not true. As I believe Will pointed out elsewhere.

Comment: @TH.: If you insist. Then please refer clearly to Will's statement or point out other sources which approve the opposite (instead of just voting down). For me [subfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) is not recommendable.

Comment: [ctan](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) Vafa Khalighi is the maintainer. I misattributed the statement. It was [Stefan's](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/what-is-the-difference-between-subfigure-and-subfloat/1968#1968).

Answer (score 114):

Here's a list of possibly obsolete packages and classes, and recommendable successors. It's not intended as a judgement – it's supposed to help in choosing packages or checking preambles. Readers can make their own decision based on the package documentation of the compared packages.

- Obsolete package(s): **Recommended successor(s)**
- [`a4`](//ctan.org/pkg/a4), [`a4wide`](//ctan.org/pkg/a4wide), [`anysize`](//ctan.org/pkg/anysize): **[`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry)**, **[`typearea`](//ctan.org/pkg/typearea)**
- [`backrefx`](//ctan.org/pkg/backref): **[`backref`](//ctan.org/pkg/backref)**
- [`bitfield`](//ctan.org/pkg/bitfield): **[`bytefield`](//ctan.org/pkg/bytefield)**
- [`caption2`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption2): **[`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption)**
- [`csvtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/csvtools): **[`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool)**
- [`datetime`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime): **[`datetime2`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime2)**
- [`dinat`](//ctan.org/pkg/dinat): **[`natdin`](//www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505/natdin.bst)**
- [`doublespace`](//ctan.org/pkg/doublespace): **[`setspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/setspace)**
- [`dropping`](//ctan.org/pkg/dropping): **[`lettrine`](//ctan.org/pkg/lettrine)**
- [`eledmac`](//ctan.org/pkg/eledmac): **[`reledmac`](//ctan.org/pkg/reledmac)**
- [`eps`](//ctan.org/pkg/eps), [`epsfig`](//ctan.org/pkg/epsfig): **[`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)**
- [`euler`](//ctan.org/pkg/euler): **[`eulervm`](//ctan.org/pkg/eulervm)**
- [`eurotex`](//ctan.org/pkg/eurotex): **[`inputenx`](//ctan.org/pkg/inputenx)**
- [`fancyheadings`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyheadings): **[`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)**
- [`filecontents`](//ctan.org/pkg/pkg/filecontents): No successor (included in the LaTeX kernel; see [`filecontents`: This package is obsolete](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/511502))
- [`floatfig`](//ctan.org/pkg/floatfig): **[`floatflt`](//ctan.org/pkg/floatflt)**
- [`german`](//ctan.org/pkg/german): **[`babel`](//ctan.org/pkg/babel)** / **[`polyglossia`](//ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia)**
- [`glossary`](//ctan.org/pkg/glossary): **[`glossaries`](//ctan.org/pkg/glossaries)**
- [`graphics`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphics): **[`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)**
- [`here`](//ctan.org/pkg/here): **[`float`](//ctan.org/pkg/float)**
- [`hyper`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyper): **[`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)**
- [`ifthen`](//ctan.org/pkg/ifthen): **[`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)** (see [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete))
- [`isolatin`](//ctan.org/pkg/isolatin), [`isolatin1`](//ctan.org/pkg/isolatin1): **[`inputenc`](//ctan.org/pkg/inputenc)**
- [`mathpple`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathpple): **[`mathpazo`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo)**
- [`mathptm`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathptm): **[`mathptmx`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx)**
- [`ngerman`](//ctan.org/pkg/german): **[`babel`](//ctan.org/pkg/babel)** / **[`polyglossia`](//ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia)**
- [`nthm`](//ctan.org/pkg/nthm): **[`ntheorem`](//ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem)**
- [`palatino`](//ctan.org/pkg/palatino): **[`mathpazo`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo)**
- [`picinpar`](//ctan.org/pkg/picinpar): **[`floatflt`](//ctan.org/pkg/floatflt)**, **[`picins`](//ctan.org/pkg/picins)**, **[`wrapfig`](//ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig)**
- [`prosper`](//ctan.org/pkg/prosper), [`HA-prosper`](//ctan.org/pkg/HA-prosper): **[`powerdot`](//ctan.org/pkg/powerdot)**, **[`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer)**
- [`ps4pdf`](//ctan.org/pkg/ps4pdf): **[`pst-pdf`](//ctan.org/pkg/pst-pdf)**
- [`psfig`](//ctan.org/pkg/psfig): **[`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)**
- [`raggedr`](//ctan.org/pkg/raggedr): **[`ragged2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e)**
- [`scrlettr`](//ctan.org/pkg/koma-script): **[`scrlttr2`](//ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)**
- [`scrpage`](//ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), [`scrpage2`](//ctan.org/pkg/koma-script): **[`scrlayer-scrpage`](//ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage)**
- [`seminar`](//ctan.org/pkg/seminar): **[`powerdot`](//ctan.org/pkg/powerdot)**, **[`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer)**
- [`sistyle`](//ctan.org/pkg/sistyle/), [`siunit`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunits): **[`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)**
- [`subfigure`](//ctan.org/pkg/subfigure): **[`subfig`](//ctan.org/pkg/subfig)**, **[`subcaption`](//mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf)**
- [`t1enc`](//ctan.org/pkg/t1enc): **[`fontenc`](//ctan.org/pkg/fontenc)**
- [`times`](//ctan.org/pkg/times): **[`mathptmx`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx)**, **[`txfonts`](//ctan.org/pkg/txfonts)**, **[`txfontsb`](//ctan.org/pkg/txfontsb)**
- [`ucs`](//ctan.org/pkg/unicode): [`inputenc`](//ctan.org/pkg/inputenc), [`inputencx`](//ctan.org/pkg/inputenx) with `utf8` option, see [`utf8x` vs. `utf8` (`inputenc`)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067)
- [`utopia`](//ctan.org/pkg/utopia): **[`fourier`](//ctan.org/pkg/fourier)**
- [`vmargin`](//ctan.org/pkg/vmargin): **[`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry)**, **[`typearea`](//ctan.org/pkg/typearea)**

I took the list from my [TeX blog](//texblog.net/latex-articles/packages/) where I started to maintain it some time ago, for sharing it here. It's in form of a list, since tables are not supported on SE posts. Feel free to suggest edits.

Comment: Is type1cm made obsolete by lmodern?

Comment: @Werner You did good; moreover, I believe that there are many versions of `psfig` around and rather different from one another.

Comment: I suggest to add: algorithm: algorithm2e (fixed hyperref problems for me), and algorithmic: algorithmicx.

Comment: What about `xifthen`?

Comment: What about `xcolor` instead of `color`?

Comment: There is also `din1505`.

Comment: I think `newtx` (= {`newtxtext`,`newtxmath`}) supersedes `txfonts`.

Comment: Some additional obsolete packages, including one on your lists: 
`times`, `nimbus`, `txfonts`:`tgtermes` or `newtx`|
`mathptmx`:`newtxmath`|
`helvet`:`tgheros`|
`cm-super`:`lmodern` or `cfr-lm`|
`avant`:`tgadventor`|

Comment: How about adding `scrlayer-scrpage` as successor of / alternative to `scrpage2`? The latter one is nearly “final” but not yet obsolete. See p. 200 in `scrguien.pdf` (p. 220 in `scrguide.pdf`).

Comment: @Tobi I took the liberty to add `scrlayer-scrpage` as `scrpage2` officially got declared deprecated by Markus.

Comment: I think it is unhelpful to classify packages in this way because those being grouped as 'obsolete' in fact have a variety of different statuses. These range from officially obsolete (declared obsolete by their maintainers, marked as such on CTAN etc.) all the way through to those which are simply less powerful than alternatives or, even, just older. **ifthen** is not obsolete in the sense that something like **times** or **t1enc** are obsolete. And, while, **times** is obsolete, **tgtermes** is not its successor any more than **lmodern** or **cfr-lm** replaces non-package cm-super.

Comment: My comment is only partially aimed at the answer, of course. It is partly addressing discussion in comments. Is the fact that the first and last items in the list relate to identical lists of successors intentional? It seems rather confusing.

Comment: Not only that, the lists seem to include conflicting information with `mathptmx` being recommended as a replacement for `times` and being itself deprecated in favor of `newtxmath`. Same thing about `txfonts`.

Answer (score 20):

If you search on the CTAN catalogue, many obsolete packages have notes pointing to the newer packages they have been superseded by. For the particular example of [subfigure](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure), its catalogue entry has to say:

> The package is now considered obsolete: it was superseded by [subfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig), but users may find the more recent [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package more satisfactory.

Whenever I find about a new package, I tend to have a look at CTAN before using it to watch out for any of these notes and also quickly browse through it's documentation.

Comment: CTAN has also 'obsolete' category/topic (probably highly underused): https://www.ctan.org/topic/obsolete

Answer (score 9):

The German-speaking forum mrunix.de includes a [thread](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=52211) about obsolete LaTeX packages and their successors. Among others, `subfig` is listed as "Nachfolgepaket" (successor package) of `subfigure`.

Answer (score 8):

I'd also like to point out that subscribing to the [ctan-ann](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/info.html) mailing list is a great way to learn about new packages (and new versions of them).

Answer (score 7):

This [document checker](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20071119021946/http://www.kohm.name/markus/TeXidate.pl) is quite old but helps perhaps with the most deprecated stuff.

I mean people are still using `eqnarray` and similar stuff even when several manuals list them as deprecated/problematic since decades.

Of course this does not help with your request for ongoing deprecation/supersede news.

Comment: I like this but it is ironic that it's *quite old*. If only this sort of tool could keep up with the German-speaking thread in lockstep's answer.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, I've updated the link.