# Why is the ifthen package obsolete?

Tags: e-tex, obsolete, conditionals

In the LaTeX companion, the authors recommend to use the package `ifthen` for complex conditional.

But in his answer to [LaTeX conditional expression](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression/5896#5896) Will Robertson doesn't mention it, and in the comments, Philipp says that the package is obsolete.

The question is in which way `ifthen` is obsolete and what are the risk to use it in a document.

Comment: Note that my comment is only a one-liner, not an exhaustive explanation. "Obsolete" here just means "for many problems there exist better solutions nowadays."

Comment: More general reference to obsolete packages: [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764)

Comment: So what about `xifthen`? Same thing? Obsolete, too?

Comment: The `\if...`, `\else`, `\fi` TeX primitives are not obsolete. The packages mentioned here are based on these primitives. The good concept is to use only these TeX primitives, no useless macro packages.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The main reason why people may consider [`ifthen`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) obsolete (last version is of 2001/05/26 with about one page of user manual plus four pages of code documentation) is that it is superseded by e.g. [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), which uses the advanced possibilities of [`eTeX`](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-etex). Using these allows faster processing. You still can use [`ifthen`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) for your existing and new documents if you like and I don't think there is a risk in doing so.
However for new code, especially new packages which use a lot of boolean expression using the more modern alternatives is recommended.

Comment: Not to mention that `etoolbox` is fantastically useful for other things too.

Comment: Perhaps to have some faster codes, the better solution is to use `TeX`'s primtives or `eTeX`'s primitives directly

Comment: @Altermundus: I prefer `\if`-switches before `boolean`s as well, but I see also the drawbacks. The way TeX is skipping *false* branches has its drawbacks. Also for more complex expressions a framework is very handy.

Comment: @Martin: I agree that for more complex expressions, a framework is very handy. Do you know some packages that use `etoolbox` (for examples)?

Comment: On the other hand, `\ifstrequal` from etoolbox doesn’t work in all circumstances where `\ifthenelse{\equal…}` works.

Comment: @Konrad: When aren't they the same?  I'd be happy to switch away from `ifthen`, but that's the one feature of it I use most of the time.

Comment: @AntalS-Z I don’t know but I had one case where their results differed on empty strings (something to do with expansion, I imagine).

Comment: @KonradRudolph and vice versa of course. Say I have `\def\a{x}\def\b{x}` – should a test comparing `\a` and `\b` give equal (because their (one-level) expansion is) or not (because they're two distinct macros)?

Answer (score 42):

From my experience in various forums and newsgroups, `ifthen` often seems to do more harm than good, especially when used by newbies. The main `\ifthenelse` command is fragile, so something like

```
\section{\ifthenelse{\equal{a}{a}}{b}{c}}
```

doesn't work. The comparison is not expandable, so that the command "possibly has only limited usefulness for macro code writers" (quoted from the `ifthen` manual). Plus I find the syntax quite cumbersome compared to e.g.

```
\ifstrequal{a}{a}{b}{c}
```

This is not a diss of the `ifthen` package; its weaknesses are known and unavoidable because it had to be compatible to an older macro package and was written long before e-TeX was implemented. I just conclude that for many problems there exist solutions with fewer problems. If you want to use the `ifthen` package, then that is fine, but you should know about its limitations.

Comment: I don't know `etoolbox` so perhaps my answer will be different in several months, but actually I know some limitations of `ifthen` and I know the problems with fragile commands (it's not possible to avoid all of them), so my first idea would be : `\DeclareRobustCommand\title{\ifthenelse{\equal{a}{a}}{b}{c}}
 \section{\title}`. Now it will be interesting to know the limitation of `etoolbox`. I agree that `etex` is virtually indispensable.

Comment: *Many* things do more harm than good when misused ;). `ifthen` has certain virtues in terms of its limited scope: `etoolbox` is rather overwhelming, I think, just because it is so powerful. So I can see arguments on both sides here.

Answer (score 13):

2024 update: Note that `etoolbox` itself, while not obsolete, has *largely* been superseded by better solutions developed by the people working on LaTeX 3. There are still some things you have to use `etoolbox` for, but conditional expressions aren't among them. Using `expl3` syntax and/or the new commands for creating commands and handling conditionals in LaTeX itself is now preferable to reliance on `etoolbox`, `ifthen` etc. These are (mostly) documented in `usrguide` and `clsguide`.

### Terminological Caution

I think that a certain degree of caution is required here in the way we classify packages. While some people may *consider* `ifthen` obsolete, it is certainly not marked officially as obsolete.

Compare [ifthen's CTAN page](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) with [subfigure's](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure).

This is not to say that there are not often better options, but the existence of better alternatives does not, just in itself, render a package obsolete.

Compare the case of packages for handling sub-figures. `subfigure` is definitely obsolete, but this leaves several other options, including both `subfig` and `subcaption`. In very many cases, the latter is preferable to the former - certainly it is more powerful, it works well with the powerful `caption` package etc. But that does not render `subfig` obsolete.

Something being obsolete means, to me, that there is good reason for me to update existing code (e.g. packages or classes for which I'm responsible) even if there are no obvious problems with it. If my code includes the use of things like `\sf` in a LaTeX document, or  loads `subfigure`, I really should do something about that if it is at all practical to do so.

But there is not the same kind of reason for me to update code which loads `subfig` or `ifthen` and so it would be misleading to describe *these* packages as 'obsolete'. They are not. Not yet, anyway.