# Does LaTeX have a built-in scripting language?

Tags: diagrams, scripts

Say I want to [draw a simple graph](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Graphics) in LaTeX.

I'm interested to know if you can write a for loop or something to create things like lines or squares programmatically in LaTeX.

Comment: Related question: [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TikZ is a powerful graphic package. It's a front end for the [pgf](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package and can be used for programming drawings such as graphs. for loops a easy with TikZ.

Have a look at

- The [TikZ Example Gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/)
- The [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) category on this site
- The extensive [TikZ and PGF manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)

If you would like to program more in general, you may consider to use [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org/), which allows using [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) as scripting language.

Answer (score 8):

You can can also use the bundle `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-5)(5,5)
\multido{\iA=-3+1}{7}{%
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,yMaxValue=4]{0}{4}{\iA*x}
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX running on top of TeX or pdfTeX or XeTeX is a [Turing complete](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Turing_completeness) [programming language](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/TeX#Macro_language), but you are probably more interested in [LuaLaTeX](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/LuaTeX), as that offers [Lua](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29), a "modern" scripting language.

Answer (score 4):

In fact TeX is itself a kind of scripting language (and it is a Turing complete programming language cf. Wikipedia article). There are packages that wraps in a neat way bare-bones TeX to supply basic imperative constructs like loops and conditionals: [forloop](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/forloop), [ifthen](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) (concerning the later see also [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/7460)). I used to use these packages, one example of mine could be found [in this directory](http://mmcs.sfedu.ru/~ulysses/Misc/cards/), basically it includes bodies of CardBodyN.tex many times in for-loop, the loop itself is located in the document.tex, you're welcome to ask further questions…).