# How to make a "condition" in a macro?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I would like to make a macro with two parameters which return a text. For instance, I want `\M{1}{5}` to return `[1,5]`, and `\M{2}{2}` to return `[2]` (because the two arguments are the same). So I need to have a "check" or condition in my macro to see if the two parameters are the same and perform different executions... How do I implement this "if" in a macro?

Answer (score 19):

To complete the list I want to present the package [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox). If you are loading [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex) the package [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) will be loaded automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% 
\newcommand{\M}[2]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{#2}%
    {[#1]}% #1 = #2 -> [#1]
    {[#1,#2]}% [#1,#2]
}
\begin{document}
Here is \M{2}{3}. Also, \M{2}{2} and \M{5}{1}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

if that are all numbers then you can use `\Mnum` instead of `\Mall`

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\Mnum#1#2{[\ifnum#1=#2\relax #1\else#1,#2\fi]}
 \def\Mall#1#2{[\def\tempA{#1}\def\tempB{#2}\ifx\tempA\tempB#1\else#1,#2\fi]} 
\begin{document}

\Mnum{1}{5} \Mnum{2}{2}

\Mall{1}{5} \Mall{2}{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using a more upper-level approach, the [`xifthen` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) provides a variety of conditional macros. Read the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xifthen/xifthen.pdf) for more information about this. In your case, you could use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen
\newcommand{\M}[2]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{#2}}%
    {[#1]}% #1 = #2 -> [#1]
    {[#1,#2]}% [#1,#2]
}
\begin{document}
Here is \M{2}{3}. Also, \M{2}{2} and \M{5}{1}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Conditional macro use]

In general, care should be taken when defining single-letter macros/control sequences, since (La)TeX defines a number of these for use in regular formatting (like `\b` for bar and `\c` for cedilla, to name a couple).

Comment: Related link: [why is the ifthen package obsolete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution using the `xstring` package. It has the advantage that it will compare numerical values, so that `\M{2}{2.0}` yields `[2]` (the first arg).  If you want strict text equality use `\IfStrEq` instead of `\IfEq`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\M}[2]{%
  \IfEq{#1}{#2}%
    {[#1]}% they are equal
    {[#1,#2]}% not equal
}
\begin{document}
Here is \M{2}{3}. Also, \M{2}{2.0} and \M{5}{1}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package you can write this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{functional} 
\newcommand\M[2]{%
  \StrIfEqTF{#1}{#2}{\Result{[#1]}}{\Result{[#1,#2]}}%
}

\begin{document}

Here is \M{2}{3}. Also, \M{2}{2} and \M{5}{1}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In OpTeX, we can use expandable `\isequal` macro:

```
\def\M#1#2{\isequal{#1}{#2}\iftrue #1\else #1,#2\fi}

Test: \M{2}{2}. \M{1}{3}.

\bye
```