# Undefined control sequence \equal in section title while using packages hyperref and ifthen

Tags: hyperref, conditionals

I have a command that uses package `ifthen`.  I use the command in section titles.  I have to protect the command because otherwise I obtained the error Undefined control sequence `\equal`.  So far, so good.  Now I started using package `hyperref`, and the error is here again.  How could I solve it?  An example follows.  Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref} % remove this line => no error
\newcommand{\something}[1]{Was something}
\newcommand{\somethingelse}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{Was X}{Was not X}}
\begin{document}
     \tableofcontents
     \section{\something{}}
     \section{\protect\somethingelse{}} % remove this line => no error
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a "condition" in a macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27293/how-to-make-a-condition-in-a-macro)

Comment: See also [Why is the ifthen package obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866)

Comment: I think it is duplicated because with the test `ifstrequal` of the package `etoolbox` everythink works well.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel There's still the warning about "Token not allowed in a PDF string" (`\texorpdfstring` may come handy).

Comment: @egreg: Sorry I didn't mentioned this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally used the tests `\ifstrequal` and `\ifstrempty` from package `etoolbox`.  As a side effect, now there is no need to `\protect` the commands within the titles.  I think that package `xstring` also solved the problem, but I needed additional tests for doing other tasks.  In summary, I switched from package `ifthen` to package `etoolbox`.

Comment: You might want to accept Achmed Musa's answer about `etoolbox` then, since it seem the most useful for you. Note that you do not get the usual 15rep for self-accepted answers anyway.

Comment: I think my answer is the most useful answer for others.  Do you think I should accept the most useful answer just for me?  About rep, I do not care.

Comment: \ifstrequal does not seem to expand the macro inside. I could not get it run with \csname #1Suffix\endcsname

Comment: @MartinScharrer: As a user who could just solve his problem with this answer, I agree this answer is much more useful than the [`other answer above`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38432/18853). The answer above provides helpful explanations, but the question on how to fix `\ifthenelse{\equal{...` in a command is most clearly solved by a command like `\ifstrequal{a}{b}{true}{false}` that's analogous to other programming languages, rather than a (in comparison to that solution) cryptic `\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{X}=\z@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{Was X}{Was not X}`.

Answer (score 6):

The *etoolbox* package has a command that I sometimes use to deal with premature expansion and *Token not allowed in a PDF*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\something}[1]{Was something}
\newcommand{\somethingelse}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{X}=\z@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {Was X}{Was not X}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
     \tableofcontents
     \section{\something{}}
     \section{\protecting{\somethingelse{X}}}
     \section{\protecting{\somethingelse{Y}}}
\end{document}
```

Another solution is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
% In case the platform has no \pdfstrcmp:
\ifdef\pdfstrcmp
  {\let\asdel@strcmp\pdfstrcmp}
  {\usepackage{pdftexcmds}\let\asdel@strcmp\pdf@strcmp}
\let\then\iffalse
\newcommand*\ifstrcmp{}
\def\ifstrcmp#1\with#2\then{\ifnum\asdel@strcmp{#1}{#2}=\z@}
\newcommand{\somethingelse}[1]{\ifstrcmp#1\with X\then Was X\else Was not X\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{\protecting{\somethingelse{X}}}
  \section{\protecting{\somethingelse{Y}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you can use `\IfEq` from the [xstring](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\something}[1]{Was something}
\newcommand{\somethingelse}[1]{\IfEq{#1}{X}{Was X}{Was not X}}
\begin{document}
     \tableofcontents
     \section{\something{}}
     \section{\protect\somethingelse{}} % remove this line => no error
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in certain situations, using this solution in my document produces `! Argument of \M@sect has an extra }.`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper And which might be your document class?

Comment: `memoir` in this case. I meanwhile managed to use `\ifstrequal` from `etoolbox` as suggested in [another answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41103/18853).

Answer (score 2):

Using the LaTeX3 packages:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \somethingelse #1
  {
   \str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{X}{Was~X}{Was~not~X}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This even gives no warning about non allowed tokens in PDF strings.

However, if this command is made in order to write different things in the section title than in the page header, a different strategy should be used.