# Proper way to detect empty/blank text

Tags: macros, spacing, conditionals

I am attempting to ignore a command if it is passed with empty/blank text. My use case is not as complicated as one [Expand away empty macros within ifthenelse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42280/expand-away-empty-macros-within-ifthenelse) where @egreg provides what seems like a great way to test if the text passed to it would produce no output.  However, I can't seem to get it to work.

When the following works the output should be just the name (if no address or an empty/blank address is given):

> **Name:** Peter's Pizza

or if a non-blank address is given:

> **Name:** Peter's Pizza
>
> **Address:** 123 Main Street, Anytown, USA

### `xstring` Version of `IfNoText`:

With my original version (with `%\def\UseEgregsIfNoText{}` commented out), Section 1 and 3 are correct.

Section 2 does not work properly in that the `Address:` is printed when it should not be.  This `xstring` version of `\IfNoText` also does not allow me to have blank lines in the `\SetAddress{}` (see second occurrence of `\UseEgregsIfNoText`) which I would like.

Furthermore, Section 4 shows that I am not able to compile if I attempt to access `\MandatoryName`. Note that it is commented out in this case.

[image]

### Egreg's Version of `IfNoText`:

With @egreg's version of `\IfNoText` (uncomment `\def\UseEgregsIfNoText{}`) obtained from [Expand away empty macros within ifthenelse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42280/expand-away-empty-macros-within-ifthenelse), I can compile with blank lines in the `\SetAddress{}` and use the `\MandatoryName` macro, but don't get the desired results.  Here Case 1 and 2 are correct, but not 3 (which has additional blank lines inserted in `\SetAddress`) and 4 (which attempts to access the value of `\MandatoryName`).

[image]

### Notes:

- I was planning to use `\IgnoreSpacesAndImplicitePars` and `\IgnoreSpacesAndAllPars` from [Looking for an \ignorespacesandpars](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23100/looking-for-an-ignorespacesandpars/23110#23110), but they don't seem to make a difference. These macros are included in the code below but are not used
- egreg does warn that tricky cases might fool ``, but I don't think that blank lines was what he meant.

### Code:

```
\def\UseEgregsIfNoText{}% 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xstring}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23100/looking-for-an-ignorespacesandpars/23110#23110
\makeatletter
\def\IgnoreSpacesAndImplicitePars{%  Not used
  \begingroup
  \catcode13=10
  \@ifnextchar\relax
    {\endgroup}%
    {\endgroup}%
}

\def\IgnoreSpacesAndAllPars{%       Not used
  \begingroup
  \catcode13=10
  \@ifnextchar\par
    {\endgroup\expandafter\IgnoreSpacesAndAllPars\@gobble}%
    {\endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\ifdefined\UseEgregsIfNoText
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42280/expand-away-empty-macros-within-ifthenelse
    \newcommand{\IfNoText}[3]{%
        \sbox0{#1}%
        \ifdim\wd0=0pt %
            {#2}% if #1 is empty
        \else%
            {#3}% if #1 is not empty
        \fi%
    }
\else
    \newcommand{\IfNoText}[3]{%
        %\edef\Parameter{\IgnoreSpacesAndAllPars#1}
        %\IfStrEq{\Parameter}{\empty}{#2}{#3}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{\empty}{#2}{#3}%
    }
\fi


\newcommand*{\MandatoryName}{\empty}%
\newcommand*{\SetName}[1]{\renewcommand*{\MandatoryName}{#1\xspace}}%

\newcommand{\OptionalAddress}{\empty}% can have line breaks, so no "*"
\newcommand{\SetAddress}[1]{%
    \IfNoText{#1}{% 
        % No printable text so ignore...
    }{%
        \renewcommand{\OptionalAddress}{\ignorespaces#1}%
    }%
}%

\newcommand*{\ShowNameAndAddress}{%
    \par\noindent\textbf{Name:}~\MandatoryName
    \IfNoText{\OptionalAddress}{}{%
        \par\noindent\textbf{Address:}~\OptionalAddress
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\section{Name with no Address}
\SetName{Peter's Pizza}
\ShowNameAndAddress

\section{Name with Empty address}
\ifdefined\UseEgregsIfNoText
    % Want to be able to handle this:
    \SetAddress{


    }
\else
    \SetAddress{
    }
\fi

\ShowNameAndAddress


\section{Name with Address Given}

\SetAddress{
  123 Main Street,
  Anytown, USA
}

\ShowNameAndAddress

\section{Name with Address using Name}

%Verify: \verb|\MandatoryName =| \MandatoryName

\ifdefined\UseEgregsIfNoText
    % Want to be able to access value of \MandatoryName here
    \SetAddress{
      123 \MandatoryName Way,
      Anytown, USA
    }
\else
    % Can't even compile in this case with \MandatoryName 
    \SetAddress{
      123 %\MandatoryName Way,
      Anytown, USA
    }
\fi

\ShowNameAndAddress

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at package ifmtarg - its purpose is to check for empty arguments.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: Did not know about that. The documentation looks promising. Do you want to post an answer showing how to use it for this case?

Comment: Please see below.

Comment: It seems the main problem here is how to detect the empty lines in that address string (and possibly remove them to make it a real empty string so that egreg's \ifnotext will detect it). Right? Some kind of macro that can take the address string and remove all the non-text characters, seems to be the one that solves problem. I too would like to know if such macro exists, or how to write such macro - essentially we are looking at reading each character in the input string and ignore the whitespaces (spaces, tabs, newline, return chars) - the rest such as \textbf{} will be taken care by egreg's

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem I converted your answer to a comment, since it's not a real answer. The space below is for actual answers.

Comment: Related Question: [How to detect that some macro expands to empty string or spaces only?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94933/how-to-detect-that-some-macro-expands-to-empty-string-or-spaces-only).

Comment: Related Question: [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I would write it.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DoIfNoText}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd0=\z@
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\MandatoryName}{}
\newcommand{\SetName}[1]{\renewcommand{\MandatoryName}{#1}}

\newcommand{\OptionalAddress}{}
\newcommand{\SetAddress}[1]{%
  \DoIfNoText{#1}
    {\renewcommand{\OptionalAddress}{\ignorespaces#1}}%
  }

\newcommand{\ShowNameAndAddress}{%
  \par\noindent\textbf{Name:}~\MandatoryName
  \DoIfNoText{\OptionalAddress}
    {\par\noindent\textbf{Address:}~\OptionalAddress}%
  }
```

Probably

```
\def\OptionalAddress{}
```

should be added to `\ShowNameAndAddress` if you want to avoid the meaning of `\OptionalAddress` to be carried over to the next address.

Blank lines in the argument of `\DoIfNoText` are irrelevant, as the box is built in restricted horizontal mode, where `\par` commands are ignored.

**Note** I've added a `\begingroup`-`\endgroup` pair to keep the assignment to `\box0` local, thus avoiding possible conflicts in some situations (see [Missing Item number in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57268/4427) and Frank Mittelbach's answer).

Comment: This works great. But one thing I don't like about it is that the macro is defined as `\newcommand{\DoIfNoText}[1]`, but takes **two** parameters. Does this not eliminate some error checking? Also, shouldn't this be called `IgnoreIfNoText`?

Comment: It's not necessary to scan the following argument twice; and error checking is just the same. The second argument is actually either to `\@gobble` or `\@firstofone`.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure this solves your problem, but for the record: package [`xifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) offers `isempty`. You can define a macro like this:

```
\newcommand{\ifempty}[3]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#3}%
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be able to handle blank lines.

Comment: @PeterGrill Nope, only "really" empty strings. You would have to trim your input first; see maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113850/tex-string-parsing-and-whitespace-stripping)?

Answer (score 3):

The following things are worth mentioning:

- Within `\SetAddress`, you redefine `\OptionalAddress` using

  ```
  \renewcommand{\OptionalAddress}{\ignorespaces#1}
  ```

  This definition only exists within `\SetAddress`. To see why this is the case, use `\OptionalAddress` just after setting the address, to see that nothing is typeset. So, you should rather use

  ```
  \gdef\OptionalAddress{\ignorespaces#1}
  ```

  which is short for `\global\def`. The reason being that you use `\OptionalAddress` in your `\IfNoText` test when calling `\ShowNameandAddress`.
- A regular space spans `3.3333pt`. However, it has no height or depth. So, perhaps you can change your definition of `\IfNoText` to

  ```
  \newcommand{\IfNoText}[3]{%
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd0=0pt %
      {#2}% if #1 is empty
    \else%
      \ifdim0pt=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
        {#2}% if #1 is empty
      \else
        {#3}% if #1 is not empty
      \fi
    \fi%
  ```

  which first checks to see if there is no width of the argument, followed by checking if there is no total height (height + depth), in the case of a space.

Including the above two suggestions yields:

[image]

```
\def\UseEgregsIfNoText{}% 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xstring}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23100/looking-for-an-ignorespacesandpars/23110#23110
\makeatletter
\def\IgnoreSpacesAndImplicitePars{%  Not used
  \begingroup
  \catcode13=10
  \@ifnextchar\relax
    {\endgroup}%
    {\endgroup}%
}

\def\IgnoreSpacesAndAllPars{%       Not used
  \begingroup
  \catcode13=10
  \@ifnextchar\par
    {\endgroup\expandafter\IgnoreSpacesAndAllPars\@gobble}%
    {\endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\ifdefined\UseEgregsIfNoText
    %% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42280/expand-away-empty-macros-within-ifthenelse
    \newcommand{\IfNoText}[3]{%
        \sbox0{#1}%
        \ifdim\wd0=0pt %
            {#2}% if #1 is empty
        \else%
          \ifdim0pt=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
            {#2}
          \else
            {#3}% if #1 is not empty
          \fi
        \fi%
    }
\else
    \newcommand{\IfNoText}[3]{%
        %\edef\Parameter{\IgnoreSpacesAndAllPars#1}
        %\IfStrEq{\Parameter}{\empty}{#2}{#3}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{\empty}{#2}{#3}%
    }
\fi


\newcommand*{\MandatoryName}{\empty}%
\newcommand*{\SetName}[1]{\renewcommand*{\MandatoryName}{#1\xspace}}%

\newcommand{\OptionalAddress}{\empty}% can have line breaks, so no "*"
\newcommand{\SetAddress}[1]{%
    \IfNoText{#1}{% 
        % No printable text so ignore...
    }{%
        \gdef\OptionalAddress{\ignorespaces#1}%
    }%
}%

\newcommand*{\ShowNameAndAddress}{%
    \par\noindent\textbf{Name:}~\MandatoryName
    \IfNoText{\OptionalAddress}{}{%
        \par\noindent\textbf{Address:}~\OptionalAddress
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\section{Name with no Address}
\SetName{Peter's Pizza}
\ShowNameAndAddress

\section{Name with Empty address}
\ifdefined\UseEgregsIfNoText
    % Want to be able to handle this:
    \SetAddress{


    }
\else
    \SetAddress{
    }
\fi

\ShowNameAndAddress


\section{Name with Address Given}

\SetAddress{
  123 Main Street,
  Anytown, USA
}

\ShowNameAndAddress

\section{Name with Address using Name}

%Verify: \verb|\MandatoryName =| \MandatoryName

\ifdefined\UseEgregsIfNoText
    % Want to be able to access value of \MandatoryName here
    \SetAddress{
      123 \MandatoryName Way,
      Anytown, USA
    }
\else
    % Can't even compile in this case with \MandatoryName 
    \SetAddress{
      123 %\MandatoryName Way,
      Anytown, USA
    }
\fi

\ShowNameAndAddress

\end{document}
```

I'm not saying this is the "proper" way. Just "a" way.

Comment: I disagree with your comment regarding the fact that "definition only exists within \SetAddress" (although I do see that it is needed for your code to work). Try commenting out `%\def\UseEgregsIfNoText{}%` and you'll see that `\OptionalAddress` actually prints something for section 3.  Perhaps you can add some text to explain this issue. Other than that I think you have improved on an @egreg solution, for which there should be a badge. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I want to show an alternative approach which is the result of @egreg, @JosephWright and me.

First of all I want to note that blank lines are a little bit strange, because a blank line sets `everypar` and this can be redefined.

Whatever here an approach using LaTeX3 in combination with `xparse`.

The argument typ `m` needs the prefix `+` to allow long arguments.

One special command is defined.

```
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \peter_if_blank_argument:N #1  {  T , F , TF }
{
   \hbox_set:Nn  \l_tmpa_box 
     {
      \tex_ignorespaces:D \tl_use:N #1 
     }
   \if_dim:w \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box = \c_zero_dim 
    \prg_return_true:
   \else:
    \prg_return_false: 
   \fi:
 }
```

The function `\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn` allows us to define a new condition. The new function `\peter_if_blank_argument:N` saves the first argument inside a hbox and test whether the dim of the hbox is zero or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_peter_setname_tl
\tl_new:N \l_peter_setaddress_tl

\NewDocumentCommand { \SetName} { +m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_peter_setname_tl { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand { \SetAddress} { +m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_peter_setaddress_tl { #1 }
 }


\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \peter_if_blank_argument:N #1  {  T , F , TF }
 {
    \hbox_set:Nn  \l_tmpa_box 
     {
        \tex_ignorespaces:D \tl_use:N #1 
      }
   \if_dim:w    \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box =    \c_zero_dim 
         \prg_return_true:
   \else:
          \prg_return_false: 
    \fi:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand { \ShowNameAndAddress } {  }
 {
  \peter_if_blank_argument:NF \l_peter_setname_tl 
      { \par \noindent  \textbf{Name:}~\tl_use:N  \l_peter_setname_tl }
  \peter_if_blank_argument:NF \l_peter_setaddress_tl 
      {
         \par \noindent  \textbf{Address:}~\tl_use:N \l_peter_setaddress_tl
       } 
  \tl_clear:N \l_peter_setname_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l_peter_setaddress_tl
 }

 \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Name with no Address}
\SetName{Peter's Pizza}
\SetAddress{


}
\ShowNameAndAddress

\end{document}
```

Comment: One of these days I **will** try to learn this syntax. But having problem adapting this to the last test case from my MWE where `\MandatoryName` is used in specifying the address.

Comment: @PeterGrill: We are taking about such code in the chat. Hope to see you there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
It is empty!%
}{%
It is not empty!%
}}
```