# How to check if a fragile macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

A similar question has been already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co), but has not been answered yet for fragile commands such as eg. `\@author`?

What would be the right way to detect if `\author` has been called with a value:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\ifXXXXXX{\@author}%
{%  
    author set \par
}{%
    author not set at all \par
    or set to \{\} () \par
    or to {\textbackslash}empty
}%

\makeatother
```

Comment: What's your issue? Fragile commands are relevant for writing to files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\@author` isn't typically a fragile command (It depends on the Author's name I suppose)
However testing its value is not related to fragile/robust distinctions.

Initialise the macro, say

```
\let\@author\@empty
```

then later test if it still has that value

```
\ifx\@author\@empty
    still empty
 \else
     author has been set
 \fi
```

Comment: I am trying to write a `.sty` file. Means the output is set outside my file. So if anyone comes up with the idea to use a set up like `\autho{Name1 \and Name2}` the conditional blows up. I would like to make it failsafe (as it can be)...

Comment: @kromo why would it "blow up"? did you try it? I assume not.

Comment: Works now. Don't know where the error came from. Only backdraw, my nice `\@latex@warning` don't work anymore (mine and the ones from `\@author`). ;-) Thanks!