# How to test if an command is empty {}?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I used `\newcommand* foo {}` to define a command so the user could set it later via `\renewcommand* foo {content}`. How do I create a conditional statement (if then else) that tests if foo is empty ("`{}`") or contains anything?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the [tag:etoolbox] package.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co (it is a more general question, but they also answered your question in the process)

Comment: `\ifx\foo\empty ... \else ... \fi` should do the trick.