# Keep the frame background in minislides

Tags: beamer

I'd like to know if it is possible to keep the background used in standard frames in minislides too:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{lion.jpg}}
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
   \blindtext
 \end{frame}
\note{no lion in the topright minislide :(}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find the background [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Lion_in_masai_mara.jpg).

As far as I understand, the content of the minislide is provided by `\beamer@frameboxcopy` inside the `\insertslideintonotes` macro from the beamerbasenote.sty file.

Is it possible to let `\beamer@frameboxcopy` keep the background of the original frame?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility would be to declare your background-image as a `pgfimage` with `\pgfdeclareimage` command and insert it in a modified `\insertslideintonotes` command.

Something like:

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\newbackground}[1]{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
       \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}}
    \pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background}{#1}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\insertslideintonotes}[1]{{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{#1\paperwidth}{#1\paperheight}
    \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformscale{#1}}%
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointorigin}\pgftext[left,bottom]{\pgfuseimage{background}}}
      \color{normal text.fg}
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\beamer@origlmargin}{\footheight}}\pgftext[left,bottom]{\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy}}
    \end{pgflowlevelscope}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  }}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{lion_in_masai_mara.jpg}}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}
\newbackground{lion_in_masai_mara}
 \begin{frame}
   \blindtext
 \end{frame}
\note{A lion in the topright minislide :(}

\newbackground{lion_in_masai_mara_2}
 \begin{frame}
   \blindtext
 \end{frame}
\note{Another lion in the topright minislide :(}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Improved version**

What's new?

1.- It's possible to use `\newbackground{}` to go back to default (empty) background. 
It uses `\@ifmtarg` command (see, for example, [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53077/1952) to [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co/53077#53077))

2.- Scoping background: `{\newbackground{figure}\begin{frame}....\end{frame}\notes{...}}` works.

3.- Smiles fixed ;-)

What's changed?

It uses `\setbeamertemplate{background}` instead of `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}` because default `background` template definition is `empty` while `background canvas` is not. Therefore it's easier to use `\ifbeamertemplateempty` condition without having to affect default background canvas.

New code and examples:

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newbackground}[1]{%
\@ifmtarg{#1}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background}[default]
     }{ 
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}}
    \pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background}{#1}
    }%
}
%
\renewcommand{\insertslideintonotes}[1]{{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{#1\paperwidth}{#1\paperheight}
    \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformscale{#1}}%
    \ifbeamertemplateempty{background}{%
      \color{normal text.bg}
      \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
     }{%
      \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointorigin}\pgftext[left,bottom]{\pgfuseimage{background}}
    }
      \color{normal text.fg}
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\beamer@origlmargin}{\footheight}}\pgftext[left,bottom]{\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy}}
    \end{pgflowlevelscope}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  }}

\makeatother

\setbeameroption{show notes}
%\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}

\begin{document}

{
\newbackground{lion_in_masai_mara}
 \begin{frame}
   \blindtext
 \end{frame}
\note[itemize]
{\item A lion in the topright minislide :)
\item Only for this frame. Next one should be empty.}
}

\begin{frame}
   \blindtext
 \end{frame}
\note[itemize]{
\item No lion in the topright minislide :))
\item As I told you.
\item Next one will have a different lion.
}

\newbackground{lion_in_masai_mara_2}
 \begin{frame}
   \blindtext
 \end{frame}
\note[itemize]{
\item Another lion in the topright minislide :)))
\item Used \texttt{\textbackslash{}newbackground\{lion\_in\_masai\_mara\_2\}} }

\newbackground{}
\begin{frame}
   \blindtext
 \end{frame}
\note[itemize]{
\item No lion in the topright minislide :))
\item Made empty with \texttt{\textbackslash{}newbackground\{\}} }

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, +1, but I'd like a more general solution

Comment: @dcmst: I've updated my answer. This solution allows to change background image. But it's not perfect, it needs always a background image. Let me learn how to use some `if` and I'll try do do it better.

Comment: this is a nice improvement but you should definitely fix your smiles :P

Comment: @dcmst: New update. Hope it helps.

Comment: This wasn't the approach I thought in the first place but it actually solves my problem, so I think it's fair to accept this answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Just as something to keep in mind: this won't honor the `\graphicspath` for the thumbnail backgrounds so the backgrounds better be in a consistent place (I hardcoded my path into the `\pgfdeclareimage` call which is ugly but works). Related: http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/41/