# Lecture notes that include my slides

Tags: article, presentations

I like add quite extensive explanations to my transparencies. I am looking for a method that is able to generate both a presentation with slides and some form of lecture notes that include my explanatory texts together with small versions of my slides as pictures in the text.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. `Beamer` for example allow to create lecture notes and slides in one file, see http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1053 for a German example. You could also extract the pages from the PDF using for instance `pdftk` and embed them in a different document.

Comment: you can also take a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120170/keep-the-frame-background-in-minislides) for an example of the beamer `\note` macro, which generates lecture notes with a "minislide" inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago I created a document class for this very purpose. It was meant for personal use, but I think it's intuitive enough for others to figure out. I put it in a [GitHub project](https://github.com/mhelvens/latex-mh-presentation) and annotated an example `.tex` file to introduce the various commands.

Use the `mh-presentation.cls` document class and run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` flag. This will generate two `.pdf` files: one with the slides and one with the handouts, based on a single source file.