# How to test whether pic text is empty in TiKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

If I wish to add a `pin` to a node in TiKZ, I can do so like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt, pin=-90:A Circle] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pin]

Now suppose I wish to draw a number of circles. I might define a custom style but suppose that 'circle' is actually a place-holder for some more complex bit of code. In that case, I might define a `pic`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \tikzset{
    my circle/.pic={
      \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt] {};
    },
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {my circle};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I wish to include text *inside* my circles, I can use the `pic text` facility to do this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \tikzset{
    my circle/.pic={
      \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt] {\tikzpictext};
    },
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [pic text=A Circle] {my circle};
    \pic [pic text=Another] at (20mm,0) {my circle};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pic texts]

Or, I could use the `pic text` to create pins:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \tikzset{
    my circle/.pic={
      \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt, pin=-90:\tikzpictext] {};
    },
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [pic text=A Circle] {my circle};
    \pic [pic text=Another] at (20mm,0) {my circle};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pic text pins]

Now suppose that some of my circles need pins and others do not:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \tikzset{
    my circle/.pic={
      \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt, pin=-90:\tikzpictext] {};
    },
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [pic text=A Circle] {my circle};
    \pic  at (20mm,0) {my circle};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pic text pins and pic text empty pins]

How can I test whether the pin text is empty or not within the pic so that I can execute the pin part of the code conditionally? I'm assuming there is a fairly easy way to do this but I just couldn't find it. Although I solved my immediate problem by bruite force, I'd like a more elegant solution.

Things I tried: the `\def\tempa{} \def\tempb ... \ifx\tempa\tempb ...` trick; the same trick with various other kinds of `def` (`\edef`, `\xdef`); various things from `etoolbox` more-or-less at random; trying to figure out a workaround using `.try` and an independent labelling system; searching the TiKZ manual; searching this site; etc. Since nothing came anywhere near working, I will not give a blow-by-blow account. Most of my attempts failed to compile. I did get some to compile, but they were insensitive to whether or not `pic text` had been specified so the code, while apparently mostly harmless, was also evidently useless.

## [egreg's tests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/39222)

This was the thread which seemed to come closest to what I wanted, albeit it not terribly close. So I tried the tests suggested there. For example, here is my attempt to apply the no-printed-output test (which I took to be the most promising):

```
 \tikzset{
    my circle/.pic={
      \setbox0=\hbox{\tikzpictext\unskip}\ifdim\wd0=0pt
        \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt] {};%
      \else
        \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt, pin=-90:\tikzpictext] {};%
      \fi
    },
  }
```

This compiles, which is good, but it treats all cases as empty, which is less good.

The `\unskip`, `\hfuzz` and `\detokenize` tests also compile but these treat all cases as non-empty (which is maybe not surprising since `pic text` has a default value, albeit an empty one):

```
  \tikzset{
    my circle/.pic={
      \if\relax\detokenize{\tikzpictext}\relax
        \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt] {};%
      \else
        \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt, pin=-90:\tikzpictext] {};%
      \fi
    },
  }
```

What is the right way to implement this test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched through the pgf souce for \tikzpictext and found the following solution (more or less):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{my circle/.pic={
  \ifx\tikzpictext\relax
      \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt] {};%
    \else
      \node [draw, thick, circle, minimum width=10pt, pin=-90:\tikzpictext] {};%
    \fi
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [pic text=A Circle] {my circle};
    \pic  at (20mm,0) {my circle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikzpictest]

Comment: Thank you! Not only does this work for the MWE, it also works more or less out-of-the-box for my actual code ;).