# Checking if a variable is not null

Tags: conditionals, comparison

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx, etoolbox}
\newcommand{\testa}{Some text}
\newcommand{\testb}{40}                                                                                                   
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
%  \ifnotnull{\testa}{\item This appears only if testa is not null}{\item Oh! testa is null}
  \ifnumgreater{\testb}{49}{\item This appears only if testb is greater than 49}{\item Oh! testb is lesser than 49} 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

What command do I use in place of \ifnotnull to check if \testa is/ is not null?

Comment: Don't use numbers in command names. Also always make *complete* examples. Beside this try `\ifnumequal{0\test}{0}...`

Comment: see the various macros in `etoolbox`, hint `\ifblank` *cannot* test on macros. But is nice to test if say `#1` is empty

Comment: @UlrikeFischer edited the question to include a MWE. Also, `\ifnumequal{0\testa}{0}did not work.

Comment: Well it did work with you previous example (where the commands contained only numbers). If the command can arbitrary text try `\ifdefstring{\testa}{}..`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree. It did work with numbers. Shows why is it important to have MWEs! And yes, \ifdefstring works as expected. Also, if you could please add that comment as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @daleif did that --- texdoc etoolbox. Thanks for reminding to RTFM :)

Comment: See also here for a related issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co