# How to define a wrapper to a command that takes an optional argument?

Tags: macros, best-practices

What is the proper way to define a wrapper to a command which takes an optional argument (such as `\chapter`)? I mean a wrapper, not a clone, such that we can inject code into the wrapper without meddling with the command of which it is a wrapper.

This is how I do it. Is there a better way to do that? (I owe the conditional clause to egreg [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/).)

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand\mychapter[2][] {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
                             \chapter{#2}
                            \else
                             \chapter[#1]{#2}
                            \fi}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter[Short title]{Long title}
\end{document}
```

`let\mychapter\chapter` will clone it, so that `\mychapter` won't be a wrapper to `\chapter`.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something.  Does `\newcommand{\mychapter}{\chapter}` do what you want?

Comment: Nope. This is not a wrapper. Suppose you want to do something else with either or both `#1` and `#2` in addition to passing them forward to `\chapter`. A wrapper would be able to do it, but your clone would not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mychapter}{som}{%
  %%% things to do before \chapter
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\chapter*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\chapter{#3}}{\chapter[#2]{#3}}%
  %%% things to do after \chapter
}
```

This supports all three calls:

```
\mychapter*{Title}
\mychapter{Title}
\mychapter[Short title]{Long title}
```

Answer (score 7):

The *traditional* way, before `xparse` allowed for more flexible solutions, is to use `\@ifnextchar[` to check for the `[` of the optional argument and to `inject` other code into the wrapper.

The starred version is included as well and can have an `[]` now as well -- it's up to the OP to decide what this `[]` should do then ;-)

```
\documentclass{book}



\newcommand\mychapter[2][]{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}%
                             \chapter{#2}
                            \else
                             \chapter[#1]{#2}
                            \fi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myotherchapter@@opt}[2][]{%
  \chapter[#1]{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\myotherchapter@@noopt}[1]{%
  \chapter{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\myotherchapter@@starredopt}[2][]{%
  % Decide yourself what to do with #1 ;-)
  \chapter*{#2}
}


\newcommand{\myotherchapter@@starrednoopt}[1]{%
  \myotherchapter@@starredopt[#1]{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\myotherchapterstarred}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\myotherchapter@@starredopt}{\myotherchapter@@starrednoopt}%
}

\newcommand{\myotherchapterunstarred}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\myotherchapter@@opt}{\myotherchapter@@noopt}%
}

\newcommand{\myotherchapter}{%
  \@ifstar{\myotherchapterstarred}{\myotherchapterunstarred}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mychapter[Short title]{Long title}

\myotherchapter{First}
\myotherchapter[Short Title]{Long title}

\myotherchapter*[Starred Short Title]{Starred Long title}

\myotherchapter*{Starred Long title}



\end{document}
```