# How to insert formatting directives into a string-appending command?

Tags: macros

The `\additem` command appends an item to a comma-separated list, and `\mylist` typesets that list.

#### Works:

```
\documentclass {article}
\newcommand\mylist {\relax}

\newcommand\additem [1]
{\edef\mylist
 {\mylist
  \if\mylist\relax\else
   ,
  \fi
  #1}}

\begin {document}
\additem {a}
\additem {b}
\additem {c}
\mylist
\end {document}
```

Now, I want to make each item bold, but not the comma. However, if I replace `#1` with, say, `\textbf{#1}`, I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.15 \additem {a}
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I make each item bold?

#### Doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mylist{\relax}

\newcommand\additem [1]
{\edef\mylist
 {\mylist
  \if\mylist\relax\else
   ,
  \fi
  \textbf{#1}}}

\begin {document}

\additem {a}
\additem {b}
\additem {c}

\mylist

\end {document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `\protected@edef` (and fix the test for emptyness)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mylist{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\additem [1]
{\protected@edef\mylist
 {\mylist
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\mylist}\relax\else
   ,
  \fi
  \textbf{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin {document}

\additem {a}
\additem {b}
\additem {c}

\mylist

\end {document}
```

Commands like `\textbf` don't survive `\edef`, because they must perform assignments. You *could* use `\noexpand\textbf`, but adding more complex items to your list would lead to the same problem (try `\additem{\'a}`).

Using `\protected@edef` neutralizes the problems with such commands. Moreover, the test `\if\mylist\relax` is wrong to begin with: in your original version (without `\textbf`), doing `\additem{aa}\additem{b}` would give funny results. Here I use a test for emptyness derived from [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/) (with the change that we need to look at the first level expansion of `\mylist`).

Another version with `xparse` that allows for more than one list and is free from this problem because it doesn't use `\edef`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\additem}{O{default}m}
 {
  \clist_if_exist:cF { l_eduardo_list_#1_clist }
   {
    \clist_new:c { l_eduardo_list_#1_clist }
   }
  \clist_put_right:cn { l_eduardo_list_#1_clist } { \textbf { #2 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printlist}{O{default}}
 {
  \clist_use:cn { l_eduardo_list_#1_clist } { ,~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\additem{a}
\additem{b}
\additem{c}

\printlist

\additem[new]{A}
\additem[new]{B}
\additem[new]{C}

\printlist[new]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you briefly explain what is wrong with my test for emptyness, please?

Comment: @eduardo.tex: Here is a reference: [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764) I'm sure there are others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the adding of new item is done via `\edef` but the macro `\textbf` is not simply expandable in `\edef`. It is much better to do adding new items to a list without `\edef`. Then all curious macros can be as parameter of `\additem`, i.e. an added item. You can correct your definition in such way:

```
\def\mylist{}
\def\additem#1{\ifx\mylist\empty \def\mylist{#1}\else
   \expandafter\def\expandafter\mylist\expandafter{\mylist, #1}\fi
}
```

Of course, if you need to have items in bold then you can replace `#1` to `{\bf#1}` at two places in the macro body (or, if you really use LaTeX then you can use LaTeX specific `\textbf{#1}`).