# Gobbling punctuation if command has no optional argument

Tags: macros, biblatex, punctuation

I want to define a new macro that gets an optional argument X and a citation key Y. If only Y is present it prints

> \cite{Y}

If, however, also X is present it prints

> X, \cite{Y}

This should in principle be done with the simple syntax of `\newcommand` which allows one optional argument with a default value which could be empty. But how do I get rid of the straying comma? Or maybe there is a way to do this with the citation command?

I've seen more general answers for the question of how to define a new command which behaves differently with and without an optional argument, but these answers seem to be quite more sophisticated than what I need here.

Comment: I should emphasize that I'm looking for a simpler solution than the general "if-branch" approach.

Comment: I don't understand *why* you want a version without if statement but I added a possible solution to my answer

Comment: It is just that my macro is already quite complicated (I just gave a minimal example to explain my need), and I don't want to clutter it even further with an extra \if construction. Your second solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that if you are really looking into this in the context of `biblatex`'s citation commands, the pre-note does something quite similar: `\cite[Cf.][]{sigfridsson}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test if the optional argument is empty. [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/) gives several possible ways how to do that. I picked one here:

```
\documentclass{article}

% traditional solution:
\newcommand*\mycommand[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    #1,\nobreakspace
  \fi
  \cite{#2}%
}

% without if statement:
\newcommand*\gobbletwo[2]{}
\newcommand*\myothercommand[2][\gobbletwo]{%
  #1,\nobreakspace\cite{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

+\mycommand{foo}+

+\mycommand[bla]{foo}+

+\myothercommand{foo}+

+\myothercommand[bla]{foo}+

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's really easy with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ocite}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {% no optional argument in the input
     \cite{#2}%
    }
    {% optional argument has been given
     #1,~\cite{#2}% note the tie
    }%
}
```

The list of arguments, instead of being a number, says

> `o` for an optional argument without a default value
>   `m` for a mandatory argument

The call `\ocite{abc}` will follow the “true” branch of `\IfNoValueTF{#1}`; conversely `\ocite[X]{abc}` will follow the “false” branch.