# How to code "if (#3 is not empty) then (do something) endif" in LaTeX?

Tags: macros

EDIT:
Answer found here: [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co)

Consider the following code snippet from a .sty file

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Snippet}[3]{% 
    \@namedef{csh#1}{\sremA{#2}{#3}}%
    \@namedef{bea#1}{\sremB{#2}{#3}}%
}%

\newcommand{\sremB}[2]{
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{#1}
    \begin{shadedrem}
        #2
    \end{shadedrem} 
    \end{frame}
}
```

I want to change this code to

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Snippet}[4]{% 
    \@namedef{csh#1}{\sremA{#2}{#3}}%
    \@namedef{bea#1}{\sremB{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}%

\newcommand{\sremB}[3]{
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{#1}
    \begin{shadedrem}
        #2
    \end{shadedrem} 
    \end{frame}
%%% Pseudo code 
if #3 is not empty then
( here I will process text in #3 )
endif
}
```

I have the following questions. How to code the "if #3 is not empty then"?, and is it possible to create a command where the last argument is optional? Such that

```
\cmd{#1}
\cmd{#1}{#2}
```

both work?

Comment: `\ifx\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax \else <do something>\fi` (needs e-TeX)

Comment: Is e-tex a required package?

Comment: Still, I would suggest you define these commands using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse).  It offers some neat features to check if arguments are empty.

Comment: What is xparse?

Comment: e-TeX is an extension to the binary program TeX, which offers additional primitives such as `\detokenize`.  This extensions are available in `pdftex`, `luatex`, and `xetex`.

Comment: I don't want to considerably change my tool stack if at all possible.

Comment: I have Miktex and TeXStudio, what other downloads are required?

Comment: `xparse` is a candidate component of the LaTeX3 format to define commands.  If you dislike the future though, stick with the solution proposed in my first comment.

Comment: `xparse` is very stable and reliable.

Comment: @ndroock1 if you are using a latex command from this century it is already using etex, that will not be an issue. although personally I don't usually bother and would use `\ifx\valign#3\valign` which is theoretically less safe as `#3` might start  `\valign`, but in practice ...

Comment: OK. I'll try to implement the solution

Comment: The first solution worked just fine.

Comment: @ndroock1: By the way: Did you have ever heard of `MWE`. It would be nice to post such ones, not just fragments of code, out of context

Comment: MWE? Have not heard of this, I am =very= newbie in LaTeX.

Comment: What should I do with the second half of the question now that this question is "Duplicate"?

Comment: @ndroock1: You've been a member for 4 years now: minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) -- and don't ask more than one issue in one question ;-). I am sure, there are questions and answers that attack the stuff about the optional argument. `xparse` would do this very easily.