# How could I get beamer's frame titles top aligned in all cases?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

The following MCE points out that, with some `beamer`'s themes, the frame titles are vertically:

- top aligned in presence of (possibly invisible) frame subtitles,
- centered in absence of frame subtitles.

How could I get the frame titles top aligned in all cases?

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Top aligned frame title if subtitle}
  \framesubtitle{Frame subtitle}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Top aligned frame title if (possibly invisible) subtitle}
  \framesubtitle{\mbox{}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Vertically centered frame title if no frame subtitle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Your tests are not complete: try with very long titles and/or subtitles. The title (and subtitle) are just stacked in a vertically centered box. 2) Each theme (or outer theme) chooses its own rules.

Comment: Article mode seems to behave the opposite, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354106/beamer-v3-40-interprets-empty-frame-titles-differently-than-previous-versions/354108 , maybe you can borrow some code from beamerarticle?

Comment: @PaulGaborit 1) I don't see your point with with very long titles and/or subtitles: they always look ugly if not alone (and don't look worse with samcarter's solution, except in the case of multilined frame title and no frame subtitle: nothing's perfect ;) 2) Indeed: that's the reason I specified "with some `beamer`'s theme[s]".

Comment: The `PaloAlto` theme uses the `sidebar` outer theme: _The frame title is vertically centered in a rectangular area at the top that always
occupies the same amount of space in all frames._ (beamer user guide, p.264). So, the frame title is not "top aligned in presence of (possibly invisible) frame subtitles" (example: a long title with two lines and a subtitle is not top aligned with a short title with a subtitle).

Comment: @PaulGaborit IMHO, this sentence of the documentation is not precise enough: it doesn't tell what's the behavior of the frame subtitle area and the relative behaviors of the frame title and subtitle areas in case of subtitle.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé _When the frame title and subtitle are to be typeset, this template is invoked with the beamer-color and -font frametitle set. This template is not invoked when the commands \frametitle
or \framesubtitle are called. Rather, it is invoked when the whole frame has been completely read. Till then, the frame title and frame subtitle text are stored in a special place. This way, when the
template is invoked, both inserts are setup correctly. The resulting TEX-box is then magically put back
to the top of the frame._ (beamer user guide, p.73)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could insert something like `\strut` in the `frametitle` template

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-\beamer@headheight%
    \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
      \vfil
      \leftskip=-\beamer@leftmargin%
      \advance\leftskip by0.3cm%
      \rightskip=-\beamer@rightmargin%
      \advance\rightskip by0.3cm plus1fil%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\par}%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}%
      \strut% NEW
      \insertframesubtitle\par}%
      \vbox{}%
      \vskip-1em%
      \vfil
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Top aligned frame title if subtitle}
  \framesubtitle{Frame subtitle}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Top aligned frame title if (possibly invisible) subtitle}
  \framesubtitle{\mbox{}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Vertically centered frame title if no frame subtitle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of insert a `\strut`, you can replace the first `\vfil` by `\vksip1mm` (this method works with very long titles or very long subtitles).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Do you want to add an additional answer that deals with long titles?