# How to define my own numeration?

Tags: numbering, indexing

I want to define my own numeration and its display.

For example,

> Today I have met David (P1) in the parking. David was friendly. Suddenly I remember he was a friend of mine, Susan (P2). ...

If I edit the text by adding

> Today I have met David (P1) in the parking. David was friendly. *David is father of John (P2)*. Suddenly I remember he was a friend of mine, Susan (P3). ...

I expect that the numbers change automatically.

Comment: Will you ever have to re-use old references to persons? Or, once they're used/defined, you'll never use/refer to them again?

Comment: @Werner I don't need to refer them. But it would be nice if I am able to. The anwsers are very good and cover both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{numerations}
\newcommand\nlabel[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{numerations}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname REF#1\endcsname{\thenumerations}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname NUMERATIONS\thenumerations\endcsname{#1}%
  #1 (P\thenumerations)%
}
\newcommand\nref[1]{#1 (P\csname REF#1\endcsname)}
\newcommand\numeration[1]{\csname NUMERATIONS#1\endcsname{} (P#1)}
\begin{document}
Today I have met \nlabel{David} in the parking.  David was friendly.
\textit{David is the father of \nlabel{John}.} Suddenly I remember he was
a friend of mine \nlabel{Susan}...

I can recall the label for \nref{John}, \nref{David}, and or \nref{Susan}.

Or I can invoke them by number: \numeration{2}, \numeration{1}, and or 
\numeration{3}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version with `\nameref` - working (if needed) and automatic labeling by using the optional argument, which refers to the name of the person, whereas an additional `\label` command *after* the `\newpersons` macro will refer to the person's number (i.e. P1 etc.)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{person}
\renewcommand{\theperson}{P\arabic{person}}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\newperson}{O{#2}m}{%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  % If hyperref is not loaded, \protected@edef\currentlabelname does no harm here
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1}% for nameref. 
  \label{#2}%
  \refstepcounter{person}%
  #1~(\theperson)%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Today I have met \newperson{David} in the parking.  David was friendly.
\textit{\ref{David} is the father of \ref{John}.} Suddenly I remember he was
a friend of mine \newperson{Susan}\label{susansnumber}...

I can recall the label for \newperson{John}, \ref{David}, and or \nameref{Susan} or call them by a reference to the number with \ref{susansnumber}. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following example provides `\newperson{<name>}` which sets the name followed by an incremented counter in the form `(P<num>)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{person}
\newcommand{\newperson}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{person}%
  #1~(P\theperson)}

\begin{document}

Today I have met David~(P1) in the parking. David was friendly. 
David is the father of John~(P2). Suddenly I remember he was a friend of mine, Susan~(P3).

Today I have met \newperson{David} in the parking. David was friendly. 
David is the father of \newperson{John}. Suddenly I remember he was a friend of mine, \newperson{Susan}.

\end{document}
```

This could be expanded to use a `\label`-`\ref` system, allowing one to reference people already named (not new), for consistency. Here is such an implementation that provides `\newperson[<tag>]{<name>}` which can be referred to using `\refperson{<tag>}`. If no `<tag>` is supplied, `<name>` is used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{person}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newperson}[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{person}% New person added
  \def\@currentlabel{#2}% Update label
  \@currentlabel~(P\theperson)% Set person
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/5764
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \label{#2}%
  \else
    \label{#1}%
  \fi
  }
\makeatother
\newcommand{\refperson}[1]{\ref{#1}}%

\begin{document}

Today I have met Davidofilofsky~(P1) in the parking. Davidofilofsky was friendly. 
Davidofilofsky is the father of John~(P2). Suddenly I remember he was a friend of mine, Susan~(P3).

Today I have met \newperson[david]{Davidofilofsky} in the parking. \refperson{david} was friendly. 
\refperson{david} is the father of \newperson{John}. Suddenly I remember he was a friend of mine, \newperson{Susan}.

\end{document}
```