# New environment with a heading and an indented paragraph

Tags: environments, indentation

I need to create a new environment that will add a heading with an indented paragraph (the indentation applies to the entire paragraph excluding the heading). This is the desired effect:

[image]

So far I've come up with this. The problem is that the indentation includes the heading as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcounter{task}
\newenvironment{task}[1][]{\refstepcounter{task}\par\medskip
{\noindent\textbf{Task~\thetask #1: }}\leftskip=2em\rightskip=2em \itshape}{\par\medskip}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{task}
\blindtext
\end{task} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way to exclude the heading from the paragraph indentation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcounter{task}
\renewcommand\thetask{\textbf{Task~\arabic{task}}}
\newenvironment{task}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{task}%\par\medskip%
  \enumerate[labelsep=*]\item[\thetask #1:]}
  {\endenumerate}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext
  \begin{task}
  \blindtext
  \end{task}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick! The label somehow went outside the text margin, so I used `align=parleft` and labelindent to make it indent inside.

Answer (score 2):

Juzst add a `\hspace*{-1em}`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{task}
\newenvironment{task}[1][]{\refstepcounter{task}\par\medskip
{\noindent\hspace*{-2em}\textbf{Task~\thetask #1: }}\leftskip=2em\rightskip=2em \itshape}{\par\medskip}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{task}
\blindtext
\end{task}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, using the hspace method, I'll need to adjust it for different task environments for `Hello` to align vertically with the beginning of following lines.

Comment: @Oxdeadbef: That is a different problem you didn't explain.  I'll post another code. In practice, what is the maximal value of the counter ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `adjustwidth` environment from [`changepage`](//ctan.org/pkg/changepage) to offset paragraph text from the margins and the force a specific indentation (negative or positive) via `\hspace*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newcounter{task}
\newenvironment{task}[1][]
  {\refstepcounter{task}\par\medskip
   \begin{adjustwidth}{2em}{2em}
      \hspace*{-2em}% Remove 2em indent
      {\bfseries Task~\thetask\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else{} #1\fi:}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764
      \space\itshape}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{task}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{task}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, the same `par`agraph `shape` is obtained through a `\parshape 2` specification:

```
\newenvironment{task}[1][]
  {\refstepcounter{task}\par\medskip
   \parshape 2 0pt \dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax 2em \dimexpr\linewidth-4em\relax
    \noindent{\bfseries Task~\thetask\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else{} #1\fi:}
    \itshape}
  {\par}
```