# hfill alignment doesn´t work

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I used the code below to format some information but the last line before the red line is not right aligned. I can`t find the problem in the code. Any suggestion? Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}
\begin{samepage}
    {\color{blue}\hrule height 2pt}
    \vspace{.1\baselineskip}
    {\Large Some important text}
    \hfill
    {\large \textit{And more}} \\ 
    {\small More some text}
    \hfill \textit{Important person:}~Me \\[.3\baselineskip]
    {Year:~2018, Volume:~1, Nr.:~1}
    \hfill
    Date 1: YYYY-MM-DD\\ 
    {Classification:~A}
    \hspace{\fill}
    Date 2: YYYY-MM-DD
    \vspace{.3\baselineskip}
    {\color{red}\hrule height 2pt}
    \end{samepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to protect end of lines in a few places, otherwise a space might appear there.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}
\begin{samepage}
    {\color{blue}\hrule height 2pt}
    \vspace{.1\baselineskip}
    {\Large Some important text}
    \hfill
    {\large \textit{And more}} \\ 
    {\small More some text}
    \hfill \textit{Important person:}~Me \\[.3\baselineskip]
    {Year:~2018, Volume:~1, Nr.:~1}
    \hfill
    Date 1: YYYY-MM-DD\\ 
    {Classification:~A}
    \hspace{\fill}
    Date 2: YYYY-MM-DD% <- Here
    \vspace{.3\baselineskip}% <- Here
    {\color{red}\hrule height 2pt}% <- Here (this one isn't necessary, actually)
    \end{samepage}
\end{document}
```

#### Edit: A comment at the end of the line? Seriously?

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399986/134574)
[is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/134574)
[something](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20577/134574)
[that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/376953/134574)
[everyone](https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/commit/ea3baab1b91c6a4eb52fc03cfb1f7fec2ba91a5f)
[already](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946/134574)
[had](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922/134574)
[problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34844/134574)
[with](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407619/134574) (the "everyone" link is the best `:P`).

What happens here is that (in normal situations) TeX interprets a line break as a space character, so when you type:

```
abc
def
```

the result is the same as if you had typed:

```
abc def
```

(notice the space after `c`). But when you type:

```
abc%
def
```

TeX ignores everything that comes after the `%`, and this includes the line break, so it is essentially the same as:

```
abcdef
```

And that's why you had a space after the `DD` in your code.

When you have the time, I suggest you read [koleygr's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376954/134574) and if you want a more lengthy explanation, my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407620/134574).

Comment: Last one isn't necessary ... but not a bad practice too

Comment: (+1)... I would add some text about "tokens" just because on a similar problem I had, this helped me to find some resources to understand... Here is the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376959/120578 [I haven't read The TeXbook yet :( ]

Comment: @koleygr Nice answer there. I'll add something here :)

Comment: @koleygr Done :)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `\vspace{.3\baselineskip}` by `\vskip.3\baselineskip` and your problem is solved. The `\vskip` TeX primitive is much more natural than LaTeX's `\vspace` which does not end the paragraph but insert vertical space between lines of current paragraphs (using `\vadjust` primitive).

A) What happens when you type

```
 end words.
 \vskip.3\baselineskip
```

Then `\vskip` ends the paragraph (using internal `\par` inserted before `\vskip`) and this `\par` consumes the space from end line. This is normal behaviour of processing of each paragraph.

B) What happens when you type

```
end words.
\vspace{.3\baselineskip}
{\color{red}\hrule height 2pt}
```

Then we have `end words.` followed by space (from end line) followed by `\vadjust` object (from `\vspace`) followed by space (from second end line) followed by color setting (from `\color` macro) followed by `\par`, which is inserted by `\hrule` primitive. The second space is consumed by this `\par` but the first space is not consumed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `minipage` rather than `samepage`. You are adding several unwanted spaces in your code; for instance, `x \hspace{<length>}` adds a space between `x` and the glue. In your case it's not very important, as you're adding infinite glue, in other cases it would be.

Also endlines count as spaces; in some cases they're removed, in other cases they aren't. It's better to have less compact code that shows more clearly your intentions.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
{\color{blue}\hrule height 2pt}

\vspace{.3\baselineskip}

{\Large Some important text\hfill
\textit{And more}\par}%<-- to preserve \par at the font size change

{\small More some text}\hfill
\textit{Important person:}~Me

\vspace{.3\baselineskip}

Year:~2018, Volume:~1, Nr.:~1\hfill
Date 1: YYYY-MM-DD

Classification:~A\hfill
Date 2: YYYY-MM-DD

\vspace{.3\baselineskip}

{\color{red}\hrule height 2pt}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

A trailing space is removed at a `\par` command (automatically inserted by a blank line). It's better if `\vspace` is issued *between paragraphs* like in the code above. Also spaces/endlines after control sequences (in the code above, `\hfill`) are not even seen by TeX.

I set the whole first line in `\Large` size, as `\large` in the part to the right would be almost indistinguishable; note `\par` before the closing brace, which ensures the correct interline spacing for `\Large` is used.

[image]