# Polymorphism macros in LaTeX?

Tags: macros

Is it possible to define two macros with the same command but expecting different number of arguments? Then, based on the number of arguments the user provides, one or the other is used. Here is an example:

```
\newcommand{\com}[1]{\text{com}({#1},r_{#1})}
    
\newcommand{\com}[2]{\text{com}({#1},{#2})}
```

Comment: optional arguments in latex should be `[]` not `{}` so `\com{x}` and `\com[i][x}`

Comment: Can you show how you would eventually use this? As in, `\com{x}` and `\com{x}{y}`, or `\com(x)` and `\com(x)(y)` or `\com[x]` and `\com[x][y]`? Or would a mixture `\com{x}` and `\com[x]{y}` suffice?

Comment: See also, [Is it possible to use {} as delimiter for an optional xparse argument? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255762/is-it-possible-to-use-as-delimiter-for-an-optional-xparse-argument) / [macros - Detect no argument in \newcommand - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409760/detect-no-argument-in-newcommand/409770#409770)

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that might work.  You can expect and/or handle any number of entries in the single mandatory argument.  Each can be accessed via the appropriate

`\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {item number goes here}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    
\NewDocumentCommand\mycommand{m}{
  \int_case:nnTF {\clist_count:n{#1}}{
        % if a single item, do stuff with it
        {1}{you~entered~\clist_item:nn {#1} {1}}
        % if two items, do stuff with them
        {2}{you~entered~\clist_item:nn {#1}{1}~and~\clist_item:nn{#1}{2}}
        % if more items etc.
   }
   {} % <-if any of the cases above match, do this, here nothing
   {\msg_error:nn {mycommand}{wrong~number~of~arguments~to~mycommand}}%<- if no cases match, do something, here issue an error.
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mycommand{blue}

\mycommand{blue,green}

\mycommand{blue,green,yellow}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg yes that would be more simple, not sure why I set the clist.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can do

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\com}{mo}{%
  \operatorname{com}(#1,\IfNoValueTF{#2}{r_{#1}}{#2})%
}
```

and call either

```
\com{x}
```

or

```
\com{x}[y]
```

If `r_` should be used in either case, the definition can be even simpler

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\com}{mO{#1}}{%
  \operatorname{com}(#1,r_{#2})%
}
```

---

Actually, it *is* possible. It's up to you if you want to break all syntax conventions of LaTeX and be prepared to get weird output now and then.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\com}{}
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nn
   { ( \{ [^\}]* \} )* } % search all braced groups
   { \c{lorenzo_com:n} \{\0\} } % pass them as single argument to \lorenzo_com:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lorenzo_com:n
 {
  \operatorname{com}
  \int_case:nnF { \tl_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    {0}{}
    {1}{\__lorenzo_com:n #1}
   }
   {\__lorenzo_com:nn #1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lorenzo_com:n { (#1,r\sb{#1}) }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lorenzo_com:nn { (#1,#2) }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\com{x}+y$

$\com{x}{y}+z$

$\com{x} {y}+z$

$\com{x}{y}{z}+u$

\end{document}
```

[image]