# A macro that detects if the same argument has been given two times

Tags: macros

I would like to have a macro `\uniqueID{...}` that causes a message in the console, or better, a crash (with a message in the console) if it has been called two times with the same argument during the compilation of document.

How to do such a macro with (La)TeX?

---

## Edit

If the macro is called two times with the empty argument, there should be no warning

Comment: You should not add further requests, however ;-)

Comment: Yes you are right. But I guess I would be able to manage this last one :) I really don't understand why I am able to code and like that but why I am so reluctant to learn TeX. It feels so complicated!!! I often dream of a massive move to something like Python+LaTeX with a good IDE...

Comment: Not necessary, in my case ... I don't like IDEs ... they hide too much. (and I don't know too much about TeX, however)

Comment: But you can't say that `\seq_if_in:NnTF` does not just look like... assembly language or some esoteric language from the 70s... Anyway: THANKS!

Comment: Well, if `\seq_if_in` is too esoteric for you, my solution was not really useful to you. Deleted it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each call to `\uniqueID{<id>}`, store a control sequence using `<id>`. That way you can check whether that `<id>` already exists and generate an error accordingly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\uniqueID}[1]{%
  % First see if #1 is empty (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/5764)
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \ifcsname ID-#1\endcsname % Check if ID already exists
      \@latex@error{ID #1 already used}{}
    \fi
  \fi
  \expandafter\def\csname ID-#1\endcsname{}% Create ID
  #1% <process ID>
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\uniqueID{} % empty

\uniqueID{foo}

\uniqueID{} % empty

\uniqueID{bar}

\uniqueID{foo} % error

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use `ID:\detokenize{#1}` to be on the secure side.

Comment: I wouldn't use `:` (try with `babel-french`).

Comment: @egreg: Good point...

Comment: @Werner Wouldn't it be better with `\gdef` instead of `\def`?

Comment: @Colas: Only if you're typically placing `\uniqueID{..}` within groups (environments) and want it to span across that.

Answer (score 5):

An approach using `listofitems`.  A concatenated list of arguments to the macro is created, and then searched for duplication.  I provide verbose output (which can be removed) to show how it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\usedIds{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\uniqueId[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro\usedIds{#1\endlinechar}%
  \setsepchar{#1\endlinechar}%
  \readlist\IDlist{\usedIds}%
  \ifnum\listlen\IDlist[]>2\relax%
    \typeout{BOOM! #1 is a duplicate.}BOOM! #1 is a duplicate.
  \else
    #1 OK.
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\uniqueId{foo}

\uniqueId{foobar}

\uniqueId{foo}

\uniqueId{foobar}

\uniqueId{foobar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a non-verbose version that types out to the console and then triggers an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\usedIds{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\uniqueId[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro\usedIds{#1\endlinechar}%
  \setsepchar{#1\endlinechar}%
  \readlist\IDlist{\usedIds}%
  \ifnum\listlen\IDlist[]>2\relax%
    \typeout{BOOM! #1 is a duplicate.}
    Abort \uniqueIdHasBeenTriggered
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\uniqueId{foo}

\uniqueId{foobar}

\uniqueId{foo}

\uniqueId{foobar}

\uniqueId{foobar}

\end{document}
```

The console is this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350)
entering extended mode
(C:/steven.segletes/TeX/Working/junk.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 72 language(s) loaded.
(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))
(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\listofitems\listofitems.sty
(C:\MikTeX\tex\generic\listofitems\listofitems.tex)) (junk.aux)
BOOM! foo is a duplicate.
! Undefined control sequence.
\uniqueId ...te.} Abort \uniqueIdHasBeenTriggered 
                                                  \fi 
l.20 \uniqueId{foo}

? 
Process interrupted by user
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an `expl3` implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\uniqueID}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
   {
    \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_colas_uniqueid_prop { #1 }
     {
      \msg_error:nnn { colas } { uniqueID } { #1 }
     }
     {
      \prop_gput:Nnn \g_colas_uniqueid_prop { #1 } { }
     }
   }
 }
\prop_new:N \g_colas_uniqueid_prop
\msg_new:nnnn { colas } { uniqueID }
 {
  Already~used~ID~#1
 }
 {
  The~ID~#1~has~already~been~used.~Too~bad.
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

A \uniqueID{A}

Empty \uniqueID{}

Blank \uniqueID{ }

A \uniqueID{A}

Empty \uniqueID{}

\end{document}
```

Of course you should add code to be executed when the ID is blank or new.

Here's the console output:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! colas error: "uniqueID"
! 
! Already used ID A
! 
! See the colas documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.36 A \uniqueID{A}

? h
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| The ID A has already been used. Too bad.
|...............................................
?
```