# optional argument

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I want a macro that takes an optional argument.

- If nothing is passed, it produces G.
- If i is passed, it produces G_{p_i}.

The following code however is facing some error "Can't use '\spacefactor' in math mode".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\cabGo}[1][\@empty]{
    \ifx\@empty#1{{\sf G}}
    \else{{\sf G}_{p_{#1}}}
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
$\cabGo$
$\cabGo[3]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can not use @ unless you enclose it in \makeatletter and \makeatother

Comment: Primarily you want to check whether an argument is empty or not. Here's how: [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is missing `\makeatletter`.

On the other hand, the code is not really well written:

```
\newcommand{\cabGo}[1][]{%
  \mathsf{G}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    _{p_{#1}}%
  \fi
}
```

The test for emptiness of the argument is more robust; also `\sf` has been deprecated for more than 20 years.

If you load `xparse`, the code is even simpler:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cabGo}{o}{%
  \mathsf{G}\IfValueT{#1}{_{p_{#1}}}%
}
```

The change requested in comments (any number of options can be given)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\cabGo}{o}
 {
  \mathsf{G}
  \IfValueT{#1}
   {
    \sb{\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { p\sb{##1} }}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\cabGo$ (no option)

$\cabGo[1]$ (single option)

$\cabGo[1,2]$ (double option)

$\cabGo[1,2,3]$ (triple option)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there an \else missing?

Comment: @RaoulKessels Indeed!

Comment: Hi @egreg, can you please make it more robust as suggested following? 
\cabGo outputs G
\cabGo[1] outputs G_{p_1}
\cabGo[2,3] outputs G_{p_2p_3} etc.

Thanks a lot in advance.