# Error while defining a newcommand

Tags: macros

I am trying to define a new command in my Latex file like this

```
\newcommand{\newchunk}[1][2]{\section{#2}\label{sec:#1}\quad}
```

But I get the following error after Latex compilation

```
ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \\newchunk.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   2
l.58 ...nk}[1][2]{\section{#2}\label{sec:#1}\quad}

--- HELP ---
This is probably caused by a \newcommand, \renewcommand,
\newenvironment, or \renewenvironment command in which a # is used
incorrectly.  A # character, except as part of the command name \#,
can be used only to indicate an argument parameter, as in #2, which
denotes the second argument. This error is also caused by nesting one
of the above four commands inside another, or by putting a parameter
like #2 in the last argument of a \newenvironment or \renewenvironment
command.
```

Don't we use `#2` to refer to the second argument? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where's the advantage of `\newchunk{label}{Title}` over the clearer `\section{Title}\label{label}`?

Comment: As egreg mention, this is not the greatest idea. Here's another reason: a lot of editors can help with cross references, they do this by looking at the `\label` commands in the source. Here you're hiding them so chances are your editor will not see these labels and include them in the choose reference interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\newchunk}[1][2]{\section{#2}\label{sec:#1}\quad}
```

defines a command `\newchunk` to have a one, optional argument that has a default value of `2`. It seems like you're after defining a command that can take an optional argument containing the `\label`. Here's a suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\newchunk}[2][]{%
  \section{#2}%
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \label{sec:#1}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\newchunk{First}

See section~\ref{sec:second}.

\newchunk[second]{Second}

\end{document}
```

The above `\newchunk` takes two arguments, the first of which is an optional label string, used in `\label`. A check is performed to see whether the user supplied anything or not. If something is supplied, it's used as a `\label`, otherwise no `\label` is issued. The second argument is mandatory and is used as the `\section` title.

Answer (score 1):

`\newcommand{<command>}[<number of arguments>]{<what the command does>}`

The second argument of `\newcommand` expects the number of arguments that the command takes. So you would want to do

`\newcommand{\newchunk}[2]{\section{#2}\label{sec:#1}\quad}`