# Lost global definition after \ifthenelse using package xifthen

Tags: macros, conditionals, grouping, ifthenelse, xifthen

I created my MWE with the help of this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144176/latex-newcommand-default-argument-is-empty?newreg=39b25021a9464a76a01187d8df11046b).

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}% provides \isempty test

\newcommand{\GlobalDef}[1][]{ %
     \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}} %
     {} %
     {\xdef\GlobalDef{#1}}
 } %

 \begin{document}
 This should be empty:\GlobalDef{}
 \par
 This should also be empty: \GlobalDef

 This should say Argument: \GlobalDef{Argument}
 \par
 This should also say Argument: \GlobalDef
 \end{document}
```

## Output:

[image: Output]

## Issues:

1. `\xdef` is not registering as a global definition in this `\ifthenelse` statement.
2. Why is there a mysterious space before `\GlobalDef{Argument}` in the 3rd line of this output?

Comment: The space is in your `\newcommand{\GlobalDef}[1][]{ %`, i.e. before the `%` character ... and there are other spurious spaces as well

Comment: Why should the  fourth line also produce `Argument`?

Comment: Note that with that definition `\GlobalDef` may redefine itself and so all subsequent calls after that may use a different definition. I'm not sure if that is intended.

Comment: Ahh I see, `\GlobalDef` is defined as a macro with an optional argument. So it should be called as `\GlobalDef[Argument]` if `Argument` is to be the argument. As you call it now, you just call `\GlobalDef` without its only optional argument and then after that have either an empty group`{}` or `{Argument}`. That means that you always hit the branch that is called for an empty argument and you *never* execute the `\xdef` in the example. Try calling `\GlobalDef[]` and `\GlobalDef[Argument]` to see what happens. I'm not sure the output makes sense, but it does what you tell it to do,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. All of the evaluations in your call to `\GlobalDef` results in being blank, since you defined `\GlobalDef` to take a single *optional* argument. So, calls to `\GlobalDef` is the same as `\GlobalDef{}` and `\GlobalDef{Argument}`, none of which use the optional argument.
2. The third call inserts an additional space as a result of [spurious spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) within your definition. If you wish to avoid the spurious spaces, you'll have to strategically place `%`, something like this:

   ```
   \newcommand{\GlobalDef}[1][]{%
     \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
       {}
       {\xdef\GlobalDef{#1}}%
   }
   ```

Your `\GlobalDef` macro is defined to replace itself via the `\xdef` without printing its (optional) argument. So, you'll never truly see any output anyway.

However, if your goal is to check for an empty argument, consider the evaluation discussed in [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764), specifically

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  <EMPTY>%
\else
  <NON EMPTY>%
\fi
```