# How to call command with optional arg using {} instead of []

Tags: macros

This is a question re: [Lost global definition after \ifthenelse using package xifthen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469625/lost-global-definition-after-ifthenelse-using-package-xifthen). I'll reference the Answer given in this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58628/optional-argument-for-newcommand) since it's clear and clean.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\test}[1][]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{omitted}{given}%
}

\begin{document}
\par The optional argument was \test[].
\par The optional argument was \test[shubidu].
\end{document}
```

## Problem:

How to rewrite the command definition of `\test` so that:

```
\test{}
```

***Output***: omitted

```
\test{shubidu}
```

***Output:*** given

## EDIT:

Thank you everyone for your tips and tricks. For some more information that may help clarify the purpose of this question:
I'm trying to define optional args using `{}` instead of `[]` because I'm in the process of making a TeX -> LyX transfer. LyX inserts an optional arg with `[]` if you click "Insert" on a drop-down menu and type the arg. Otherwise, LyX will insert your arg with `{}` if you do what I've done below. I would like to keep the formatting of what I've done below which is written with this: `\newcommand{\BriefName}[1]{\xdef\BriefName{#1}}` but make the argument inserted for `\BriefName` optional. Thus, if the LyX user enters nothing in the `\BriefName` line, the program still compiles, with an "empty" argument for the \BriefName command.

[image]

## Updated MWE:

This is more what I'm looking for. I created this thanks to this [Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\BriefName}[1]{ %
        \xdef\BriefName{#1}\ifx\BriefName\empty
          {}%
        \else
          {#1}%
        \fi
}%

\begin{document}
\par This should be empty:\BriefName{}
\par This should also be empty: \BriefName
\par This should say Argument: \BriefName{Argument}
\par This should also say Argument: \BriefName
\end{document}
```

Comment: So strictly speaking, the argument is mandatory, but it may be empty. (Which is different from the usual meaning of *optional argument* in LaTeX, where one has `\foo` without opt. arg. and `\foo[shubidoo]` with opt. arg.)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/35864 may be interesting.

Comment: This is confusing syntax and is not recommended, but it is possible with `\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{+g}{\IfValueF{#1}{omitted}{given}}` from `xparse`

Comment: why are you using the iftenelse test there at all, rather than just use the optional argument? In both your uses `\test[]` and `\test[shubidu]` you have _used_ the optional argument, but you have defined the argument to be optional so you could just use `\test` if you do not need the argument.

Comment: Thank you for these comments, they were helpful. @DavidCarlisle yes I agree with you that `\test[]` can be called simply as `\test{}` and this was badly represented in my question/MWE. The issue is in LyX, once I create a command that I want to be used written like this: `\newcommand{\BriefName}[1]{\xdef\BriefName{#1}}` the LyX application will automatically call the command as `\BriefName{Argument}` if the user types anything or as `\BriefName{}` if the user types nothing. In the latter case, the document breaks as a result of this LyX feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `xparse`; the trick is *not* redefining `\BriefName` as you're trying to do, but *another* control sequence holding the current value (empty at the beginning).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\BriefName}{g}
 {
  \IfNoValueF{#1}
   {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_jalep_briefname_tl { #1 }
   }
  \tl_use:N \g_jalep_briefname_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \g_jalep_briefname_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This should be empty:\BriefName

This should also be empty: \BriefName[]

This should say Argument: \BriefName{Argument}

This should also say Argument: \BriefName

\end{document}
```

However, the standard LaTeX syntax uses `[]` for optional arguments, so it would be much better to stick with it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\BriefName}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueF{#1}
   {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_jalep_briefname_tl { #1 }
   }
  \tl_use:N \g_jalep_briefname_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \g_jalep_briefname_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This should be empty:\BriefName

This should also be empty: \BriefName[]

This should say Argument: \BriefName[Argument]

This should also say Argument: \BriefName

\end{document}
```

[image]

The version with `[]` also admits a solution with classical tools.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\BriefName}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \gdef\jalepbriefname{#1}%
  \fi
  \jalepbriefname
}
\def\jalepbriefname{}

\begin{document}

This should be empty:\BriefName

This should also be empty: \BriefName[]

This should say Argument: \BriefName[Argument]

This should also say Argument: \BriefName

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! Can I ask how to change the first solution with `{}` so that optional arg is only printed when called like: `\BriefName` and not when inserting the optional argument in: `\BriefName{Argument}`? Your solution perfectly answered my question asked here but I simplified the need of my final TeX document for this question.

Comment: @Jalep Sorry, I know nothing about LyX and don't want to. If a tool imposes its will on you, change the tool.

Comment: Ok, no worries. Thanks so much for your solution anyway -- it was helpful and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To get what you ask you just need to delete `[]` in the declaration

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{omitted}{given}%
}

\begin{document}

The optional argument was \test{}.

The optional argument was \test{shubidu}.

\end{document}
```

However the original example appears to have been mis-using the optional argument syntax.

The intended syntax for the "not given" case is `\test` not `\test[]`

So you do not need to test for an empty argument, latex has already tested for `[` being present:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\test}[1][default]{#1\ldots}

\begin{document}

The optional argument was \test.

The optional argument was \test[shubidu].

\end{document}
```