# How to create a string comparison with xparse's \NewDocumentCommand?

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

My MWE was created with the help of these two Q&As: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195491/ifthenelse-equal-string-comparison-fails) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470137/how-to-call-command-with-optional-arg-using-instead-of/470146#470146).

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

% Command declaring a global definition if argument not empty, and using a pre-defined empty definition if argument empty
\ExplSyntaxOn%
\NewDocumentCommand{\Client}{g}%
  {%
     \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
      {%
        \tl_use:N \g_jalep_client_tl%
      }%
      {%
        \tl_gset:Nn \g_jalep_client_tl {#1}%
      }%
  }%
\tl_new:N \g_jalep_client_tl%
\ExplSyntaxOff%

% Attempt using \pdfstrcmp 
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{Adam}=0 %
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {Adam}
    {Eve}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Client{Adam}
% Attempt using xstring
\par My client should be Adam: \IfSubStr{Adam}{\Client}{Adam}{Eve}
% Attempt using \pdfstrcmp
\par My client should be Adam: \foo{\Client}
\end{document}
```

## Output:

[image]

## Notes:

1. The `\IfSubStr` and `\foo` line work when there exists something like: `\newcommand{\Client}{Adam}` or `\newcommand{\Client}{Eve}` or `\newcommand{\Client}{Anything}`.
2. From this, I'm inclined to believe `\Client` produces something other than a string? How do I change this/convert this/work with this when I'm trying to create an if-else statement?

## Question:

How do I make a string comparison with the `\NewDocumentCommand` shown in my MWE? Something like: `If \Client = Adam, then print: Adam, else print: Eve`

Comment: Are you open to alterations to the definition of `\Client`?

Comment: @Werner Yes, though in my document: 1. `\Client` is always called either empty like this: `\Client{}` or with any argument like this: `\Client{Argument}`. 2. `\Client{}` or `\Client{Argument}` should print nothing, and only the command `\Client` should print whatever the global definition defined with `\Client` is

Comment: So, a first call to `\Client{<name>}` destroys its and just stores the `<name>`.

Comment: @Werner Yes! Correct

Comment: What about [this](https://pastebin.com/E70JBfgA)?

Comment: Yes, that's very good! Clean, simple, and works great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88355/discussion-between-jalep-and-werner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following doesn't use LaTeX3, but works the way you want it, both using [`xstring`](//ctan.org/pkg/xstring) and `\pdfstrcmp`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\Client}[1]{\renewcommand{\Client}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{Adam}=0 %
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {Adam}
  {Eve}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Client{Adam}

% Attempt using xstring
My client should be Adam: \IfSubStr{Adam}{\Client}{Adam}{Eve}

% Attempt using \pdfstrcmp
My client should be Adam: \foo{\Client}

\end{document}
```