# Detect empty or null output from xstring's StrBetween

Tags: xstring, xifthen

I have some code for formatting names. However, the `ifempty` macro from `xifthen` is unable to detect empty/null output from `xstring` macros such as `StrBetween`. The same goes for the `\equal {}` method. How can I detect empty output from `StrBetween`? The below code for some reason compiles and does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\name}{John Doe}

\newcommand{\middleinitial}{%
    \StrBetween{\name}{ }{.}
}

\newcommand{\test}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{\middleinitial}}%
        {Whoo hoo!}%
        {Not whoo hoo.}
}

\begin{document}

\test

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Werner I've opened a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470467/use-xstring-to-substitute-reformatted-names-in-strings

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've opened a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470467/use-xstring-to-substitute-reformatted-names-in-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\middleinitial` is not expandable, and therefore you cannot properly test whether there is a middle initial in `\name` or not. You'll have to store the output (the middle initial) *first* using the optional argument at the end of `\StrBetween{<str>}{<from>}{<to>}[<macro>]` and then you can [check for an empty argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\name}{John Doe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\middleinitial}{%
  \StrBetween{\name}{ }{.}[\@middleinitial]%
}

\newcommand{\test}{%
  \middleinitial% Find middle initial
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\@middleinitial}\relax
    Whoo hoo!% No middle initial
  \else
    Not whoo hoo.% A middle initial
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test % Whoo hoo.

\renewcommand{\name}{John F. Doe}%
\test % Not whoo hoo!

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is this monstrosity: `\expandafter\if\expandafter\relax\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\@middleinitial}\relax`?

Comment: Also, thank you for your fast solution : ) Isn't it possible to do `\StrBetween{\name}{ }{.}[\middleinitial]` without the `newcommand` statement?

Comment: @AdamErickson: The monstrosity can be made shorter (updated in the answer). It's required to expand `\@middleinitial` before it being processed by `\detokenize`, hence the `\expandafter`.

Comment: @AdamErickson: You mean is it necessary to have a `\newcommand{\middleinitial}`? It's not necessary. You can include `\StrBetween{\name}{ }{.}[\@middleinitial]` as part of `\test`.

Comment: Thank you, that is much cleaner and easier to comprehend!

Comment: Question: how can I use the output of a command calling`middleinitial` in `IfSubStr`? Currently, it does not correctly match strings.

Comment: @AdamErickson: Can you provide an example? Perhaps posting the code on [Pastebin](//pastebin.com)?

Comment: Updated: https://pastebin.com/JqSZWMQU The `\surnamefirst` and `\surnamelast` commands work as expected in tests in terms of string output. Also, `\StrSubstitute` works when using raw string inputs.

Comment: @AdamErickson: That paste has been removed...?

Comment: This one will remain longer: https://pastebin.com/hb1U1zCa

Comment: @AdamErickson: Can you provide a complete example? Something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`? Also, avoid using `\middle` for your middle initial storage; it's already defined within the context of `\left`...`\middle`...`\right`...

Comment: Edited: Here is a complete example: https://pastebin.com/aF9gKsz7. What should happen is that the `\name` should be reformatted to the citation style, matched in the bibliography, and substituted with bold text.

Comment: @AdamErickson: Under `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, `\bibitem` is defined to be `\bibitem[<title>]{<label>}`. Your redefinition using `\def\bibitem#1#2{...}` does not take the optional argument into account, leading to problems.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new to this. How should it be implemented? It was not throwing an error for me. Here, it says that this would simply generate a number (http://www.stat.unipg.it/tex-man/ltx-205.html).

Comment: @AdamErickson: So all you want is for the author titles to be **bold**?

Comment: Yes, just for the single author name (e.g., `William Fulton`). So, where it shows up as `W. Fulton` or `Fulton, W.` it should be made bold.

Answer (score 4):

Werner already explained, why `\middleinitial` isn't expandable due to the usage of `xstring` macros.

I present a shorter way in order to test for the emptiness of `\middleinitial` by using `\ifblank` from `etoolbox` package. There are still two `\expandafter` statements required, but not a bunch of 5 of them. In addition, I find `etoolbox` much more convenient than `ifthen` or `xifthen`.

`\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\middleinitial}{true branch}{false branch}` is necessary, because `\ifblank` does not expand its first argument, i.e. without `\expandafter` the macro 'sees' `\middleinitial`, but not what the content which is stored in that macro. It must be expanded first before `\ifblank` performs the test.

The `\expandafter` primitive looks ahead of `\ifblank`, i.e. it ignores `\ifblank` first and detects the `{` of the first argument. Unfortunately, this is not what is desired (and not expandable anyway), so we must jump over `{` again, i.e.

`\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\middleinitial}{...}{...}`

will allow TeX/LaTeX to 'jump' over `\ifblank` to the second `\expandafter`, that jumps over `{` to `\middleinitial` and expands that sequence -- after this is done, TeX continues with `\ifblank{expanded version of \middleinitial}{...}{...}` and performs the test finally.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\name}{John C.  Doe}

\newcommand{\othername}{John Doe}


\newcommand{\testinitial}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \StrBetween{#1}{ }{.}[\middleinitial]%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\middleinitial}{#2}{#3}%
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}



\testinitial{\name}{Whoo hoo!}{Not whoo hoo.}

\testinitial{\othername}{Whoo hoo!}{Not whoo hoo.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AdamErickson: You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Werner and @ChristianHupfer! Based on your solutions, I've found another solution using `xstring` that appears quite clean:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\name}{John Doe}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\middleinitial}{%
  \StrBetween{\name}{ }{.}[\@middleinitial]%
}

\newcommand{\test}{%
  \middleinitial % Find middle initial
  \IfStrEq{\@middleinitial}{}%
    {Whoo hoo!}%
    {Not whoo hoo.}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \test % Whoo hoo.

  \renewcommand{\name}{John F. Doe}%

  \test % Not whoo hoo!

\end{document}
```

I've posted a follow-up question with a more vexing expansion problem related to `\IfStrEqual` and `\IfSubStr` here ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470467/use-xstring-to-substitute-reformatted-names-in-strings)) if anyone can help.