# Use value from xparse key-value store in regular expressions

Tags: expl3, xparse

This is an extension of a previous question ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470467/use-xstring-to-substitute-reformatted-names-in-strings)). I would like to include the following `xparse` key-value store holding a `name` value into the document below:

```
% Key-value store
\ExplSyntaxOn 

\prop_new:N \list_prop

\keys_define:nn {bio} {%
    name  .code:n={ \prop_put:Nnn \list_prop {name}  {#1} },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\update}{+m}{%
    \keys_set:nn {bio} {#1}%
}

\cs_new:Npn \getvalue#1{%
    \prop_item:Nn \list_prop {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Default variable values
\update{%
    name={John Doe}
}
```

I would like to use the stored `name` to automatically update `l_adam_name_full_tl` defined in `\adam_name_define:n` below. In other words, `l_adam_name_full_tl` would be defined automatically based on values in the above key-value store. It would be ideal to retain the `\definename` function for flexibility, but to make its default value `\getvalue{name}` when an argument is not passed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definename}{m}
 {
  \adam_name_define:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\makebold}{m}
 {
  \adam_name_makebold:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_adam_name_full_tl
\tl_new:N \l_adam_name_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_adam_name_last_tl
\tl_new:N \l_adam_name_initials_tl
\tl_new:N \l__adam_name_input_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adam_name_define:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_adam_name_full_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_adam_name_first_tl \l_adam_name_full_tl
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_adam_name_last_tl \l_adam_name_full_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { (.*)\s[^\s]*\Z } { \1 } \l_adam_name_first_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { .*\s([^\s]*)\Z } { \1 } \l_adam_name_last_tl
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_adam_name_initials_tl \l_adam_name_first_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]+ } { \1. } \l_adam_name_initials_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adam_name_makebold:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__adam_name_input_tl { #1 }
  % full name
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   {
    (
     \u{l_adam_name_full_tl}                                   % name surname
     |
     \u{l_adam_name_initials_tl} \s \u{l_adam_name_last_tl}    % initials surname
     |
     \u{l_adam_name_last_tl} , \s \u{l_adam_name_first_tl}     % surname, name
     |
     \u{l_adam_name_last_tl} , \s \u{l_adam_name_initials_tl}  % surname, initials
    )
   }
   { \c{textbf} \cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
   \l__adam_name_input_tl
  % print
  \tl_use:N \l__adam_name_input_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \definename{John Doe}

  \makebold{His name was John Doe.}

  \makebold{His name was J. Doe.}

  \makebold{His name was Doe, J..}

  \definename{John T. Doe}

  \makebold{His name was John T. Doe.}

  \makebold{His name was J. T. Doe.}

  \makebold{His name was Doe, J. T..}

\end{document}
```

Expected output:

His name was **John Doe**.

His name was **Doe, John**.

His name was **J. Doe**.

His name was **Doe, J.**.

His name was **John T. Doe**.

His name was **J. T. Doe**.

His name was **Doe, J. T.**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn` instead of defining keys, but that's not the main point.

Here I define `\update` to populate the property list and also to call `\adam_name_define:x` to extract the `name` property. Here you see one of the advantages of `expl3`: the function is just a variant of `\adam_name_define:n` which does full expansion of its argument before doing the work.

See the other answer for comments to the regex code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definename}{m}
 {
  \adam_name_define:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\makebold}{m}
 {
  \adam_name_makebold:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeboldlastname}{m}
 {
  \adam_name_makebold_lastname:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\update}{m}
 {
  \prop_clear:N \l_adam_name_bio_prop
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_adam_name_bio_prop { #1 }
  \adam_name_define:x { \prop_item:Nn \l_adam_name_bio_prop { name } }
 }

\prop_new:N \l_adam_name_bio_prop
\tl_new:N \l_adam_name_full_tl
\tl_new:N \l_adam_name_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_adam_name_last_tl
\tl_new:N \l_adam_name_initials_tl
\tl_new:N \l__adam_name_input_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adam_name_define:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_adam_name_full_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_adam_name_first_tl \l_adam_name_full_tl
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_adam_name_last_tl \l_adam_name_full_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { (.*)\s[^\s]*\Z } { \1 } \l_adam_name_first_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { .*\s([^\s]*)\Z } { \1 } \l_adam_name_last_tl
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_adam_name_initials_tl \l_adam_name_first_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]+ } { \1. } \l_adam_name_initials_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \adam_name_define:n { x }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adam_name_makebold:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__adam_name_input_tl { #1 }
  % full name
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   {
    (
     \u{l_adam_name_full_tl}                                   % name surname
     |
     \u{l_adam_name_initials_tl} \s \u{l_adam_name_last_tl}    % initials surname
     |
     \u{l_adam_name_last_tl} , \s \u{l_adam_name_first_tl}     % surname, name
     |
     \u{l_adam_name_last_tl} , \s \u{l_adam_name_initials_tl}  % surname, initials
    )
   }
   { \c{textbf} \cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
   \l__adam_name_input_tl
  % print
  \tl_use:N \l__adam_name_input_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adam_name_makebold_lastname:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__adam_name_input_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { (\u{l_adam_name_last_tl}) }
   { \c{textbf} \cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
   \l__adam_name_input_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__adam_name_input_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\update{
  name=John Doe,
  town=London,
  birth=1888-05-01,
}

\makebold{His name was John Doe.}

\makebold{His name was J. Doe.}

\makebold{His name was Doe, John.}

\makebold{His name was Doe, J. again.}

\makeboldlastname{Again, Doe was his last name.}

\makebold{Jackson, Bob and J. Doe.}

\update{
  name=John T. Doe,
  town=New York,
}

\makebold{His name was John T. Doe.}

\makebold{His name was J. T. Doe.}

\makebold{His name was Doe, John T. again.}

\makebold{His name was Doe, J. T. again.}

\makeboldlastname{Again, Doe was his last name.}

\definename{Brutus Cyclops Dull}

\makebold{His name was Brutus Cyclops Dull.}

\makebold{His name was B. C. Dull.}

\makebold{His name was Dull, Brutus Cyclops again.}

\makebold{His name was Dull, B. C. again.}

\makeboldlastname{Again, Dull was his last name.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The trouble with this is that `\update` needs to be called behind the scenes within a class file. In other words, before `\begin{document}`. Also, the current version doesn't work to boldface the author name when overriding `bibitem` and parsing the second argument as an input to `\makebold`.

Comment: Nevermind! I have a version working now using the original key definitions. The only thing I'm having trouble with is that it is only applying boldfacing to the last bibliography entry for some reason...?

Comment: Also, `expl3` is quickly growing on me now that I'm starting to understand it.