# Using pgfopts to set up a tcolorbox style

Tags: tcolorbox, package-writing, pgfkeys, package-options, pgfopts

Consider a package file `eqbox.sty`:

```
% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{eqbox}[2018/01/01 Boxed Equations]

% Packages
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{fancybox}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Options
\pgfkeys{
    /eqbox/.cd,
    colframe/.store in = \colframe,
    colframe/.default = {black},
    colback/.store in = \colback,
    colback/.default = {white},
    shadow/.store in = \shadow,
    shadow/.default = {black},
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions*

% Body
\tcbset{
    highlight math style={
        enhanced,
        sharp corners,
        breakable,
        colframe=\colframe{},
        colback=\colback{},
        boxrule=0.4pt,
        shadow={2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{\shadow{}},
        boxsep = 3pt,
        left = 0pt,
        right = 0pt,
        top = 0pt,
        bottom = 0pt
    }
}
```

and a `.tex` file that uses this package:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, onecolumn]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eqbox}

% Body
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{x^2 + 3}
\end{equation}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I am a beginer with `pgf` and what I tried does not seem to work. What I would like to do is have three options in the package: `colback`, `colframe` and `shadow`. For example with the syntax:

```
\usepackage{eqbox}
```

or

```
\usepackage[shadow=blue]{eqbox}
```

or

```
\usepackage[%
    colback=red,
    shadow=\color[RGB]{100,150,200},
]{eqbox}
```

For the sake of the example, I would like:

- `colframe` to be `blue` by default
- `colback` to be `undefined` by default
- `shadow` to be `undefined` by default (and if `shadow` is `undefined`, don't want this line `shadow={2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{\shadow{}}` to appear in the `tcbset`)

I also don't want to "pollute" the global namespace, so from the package user's standpoint I don't want the command `\shadow` to be known in the main `tex` file (I want it to be an internal detail of the package `eqbox`).

How to do that in the cleanest possible way?

Comment: For internal commands use the `@` within the command name. Concerning "is it the right thing to do": Why not simply doing a `\tcbset` with default parameters and providing an optional argument for the macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you call `\pgfkeys{key1, key2=value2, ...}` is determined by the rules documented in section 86 of the [pgf manual](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Note that the `\pgfkeys` command is part of the [`pgfkeys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys?lang=en) package, while `\ProcessPgfPackageOptions` comes from [`pgfopts`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfopts?lang=en). This command effectively calls `\pgfkeys{/package/key=value}` for every `key=value` pair passed to the package options. In your case,

```
\usepackage[shadow=blue]{eqbox}
```

will be processed inside `eqbox.sty` as if by calling `\pgfkeys{/eqbox/shadow=blue}`.

Note that

```
\pgfkeys{/path/key=...}
```

is the same as

```
\pgfkeys{
  /path/.cd,
  key=...
}
```

Although the equals sign makes it seem so, `\pgfkeys{key=value}` is not actually an assignment. To make it behave like an assignment, you would need to first call

```
\pgfkeys{key/.store in=\someMacroName}
```

after which, calling `\pgfkeys{key=value}` will define the macro `\someMacroName` to `value`.

You might also be confused with the meaning of

```
\pgfkeys{key/.default=value}
```

which does not assign a default value to `key`; rather, it causes all subsequent calls to `\pgfkeys{key}` to behave as `\pgfkeys{key=value}`.

Putting it all together, your example becomes:

```
% eqbox.sty

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{eqbox}[2018/01/01 Boxed Equations]

\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\pgfkeys{
  /eqbox/.cd,  % Change the prefix path to /eqbox/
  %
  colframe/.store in=\colframe, % Make subsequent calls to 
                                % \pgfkeys{/eqbox/colframe=<value>}
                                % cause \def\colframe{<value>}
  %
  colframe=black,   % Hence, this causes \def\colframe{black},
                    % which is effectively a default value.
  %
  % Same for the rest of the keys.
  colback/.store in=\colback,
  colback=white,
  shadow/.store in=\shadow,
  shadow=black
}

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/eqbox} % If the .tex file contains
                                  % \usepackage[shadow=purple]{eqbox},
                                  % that would result in the call
                                  % \pgfkeys{/eqbox/shadow=purple}.
                                  % This will in turn cause \def\shadow{purple},
                                  % because of the .store handler.

\tcbset{
  highlight math style={
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    breakable,
    colframe=\colframe,
    colback=\colback,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    shadow={2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{\shadow},
    boxsep=3pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt
  }
}
```

```
% .tex file that uses the package

\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage[shadow=purple]{eqbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{x^2 + 3}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

If you want to detect whether the package user supplied a value for an option, say `myoption`:

```
% In mypackage.sty

\def\someDefaultValue{myDefaultValue}

\pgfkeys{
  /mypackage/myoption/.store in=\myoption,
  /mypackage/myoption=\someDefaultValue
}

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mypackage}

\ifx\someDefaultValue\myoption
  % User did not supply myoption=value
\else
  % User supplied some value,
  % now stored in \myoption
\fi
```

For this last part, also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/80468.