# Why does parameter double when used in caption?

Tags: macros, captions

I wrote some commands, recently adding some convenience command `\FS` to add figure sources:

```
\newcommand{\FS}[1]{%
\protect\\{\protect\scriptsize{}Bildquelle: #1}}
```

I don't know whether this is correct (all those `\protect`), but it seems to work inside `\caption`.
Unfortunately I tried to improve the command, adding an optional parameter:

```
\newcommand{\FS}[2][Bildquelle]{%
\protect\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
\protect\\{\protect\scriptsize{}#2}
\protect\\{\protect\scriptsize{}#1: #2}}
```

When using the variant with no optional parameter specified, the effect is that expanded `#2` is output, followed by expanded `Bildquelle: #2` (Actually even when specifying the optional parameter the output is duplicated as described).
For example:

[image: Example showing duplicate expanded <code>#2</code>]

I'm not deep enough into TeX to to able to fix the problem myself, even after reading those answers on `\protect`.
How should the command be written?

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\FS}[2][Bildquelle]{%
\protect\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
\protect\\{\protect\scriptsize{}#2}}{%
\protect\\{\protect\scriptsize{}#1: #2}}}`.

Comment: One pair of braces to rule them all ;-) That did it, thanks!

Comment: Is `\DeclareRobustCommand` available in all environments, or do I need spacial packages for it? My LaTeX knowledge is a bit outdated...

Comment: @U.Windl I just deleted my answer (which also cancelled any reputation-gainings) as it is obsolete: As I overlooked and as [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) pointed out in a comment to my answer, commands defined in terms of `\newcommand` are already made robust in case of having an optional argument. Thus all the `\DeclareRobustCommand`-thingies shown in my (now deleted) answer aren't needed at all. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `\ifthenelse{<condition>}{<true>}{<false>}` requires `<true>` and `<false>` to be grouped. If not, the two tokens following the `<condition>` are assumed to denote `<true>` and `<false>`. In your setup, `<true>` is `\protect` and `\\` is `<false>`. You were probably looking for something like

```
\newcommand{\FS}[2][Bildquelle]{%
  \protect\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\protect\\{\protect\scriptsize{}#2}}
    {\protect\\{\protect\scriptsize{}#1: #2}}}
```

Using the conditional test in [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764), you can instead define `\FS` to be

```
\newcommand{\FS}[2][Bildquelle]{%
  \\
  \scriptsize
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    #1: 
  \fi
  #2%
}
```

Here's a complete minimal example of the use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\FS}[2][Bildquelle]{%
  \\
  \scriptsize
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    #1: 
  \fi
  #2%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some caption. \FS{abc}}
  \caption{Another caption. \FS[abc]{def}}
  \caption{Final caption. \FS[]{ghi}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```