# When doesn't `\\` start a new line in `\caption`?

Tags: macros, captions, line-breaking

Using the command in [Why does parameter double when used in caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518624/why-does-parameter-double-when-used-in-caption/518637#518637), it works in most cases, but in a few cases (like 1 out of 20) `\\` does not start a new line.

For example using

```
\begin{table}
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
\textbf{Bezeichnung} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{z} &
$\mathbf{u'_N}$ & $\mathbf{v'_N}$ \\
\hline
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...
%...
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Koordinaten ausgewählter Weißpunkte]%
{\label{\Lt{Weisspunkte}}Koordinaten ausgewählter Weißpunkte%
\FS[Quelle]{\cite[S.~279]{poynton_digital_2012}\index{Illuminant}}}
\end{table}
```

in a table does not start a new line before `Quelle`, like this (see yellow line; rest of page pixelated to emphasize the important parts and to improve image compression):
[image: Appearance in sample page]

Or shown in detail:

[image: Detail: No line-break inserted]

Note that the same command inserts a line-break before "Bildquelle:" in the figure above the table.
I could not find a reference to a similar problem; could it be that LaTeX tried to avoid the line-break if vertical space on the page is tight?

**Additions**

For those who failed to find the `\\`, here it is (answer from the reference):

```
\newcommand{\FS}[2][Bildquelle]{%
  \protect\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\protect\\{\protect\scriptsize{}#2}}
    {\protect\\{\protect\scriptsize{}#1: #2}}}
```

Forcing table 6.1 on a new page did not change the behavior.
Making the caption text a bit longer or shorter also did not change the behavior.
However when I changed the caption to

```
\caption[Koordinaten ausgewählter Weißpunkte]%
{\label{\Lt{Weisspunkte}}Lorem ipsum Koordinaten ausgewählter Weißpunkte%
\FS[Quelle]{\cite[S.~279]{poynton_digital_2012}\index{Illuminant}}}
```

then the table went to the next page, and the line break was inserted:

[image: Correct caption with "Lorem ipsum"]

**MWE**

Finally I managed to create a MWE (pdflatex, actually it was easier than expected):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
\newcommand{\FS}[2][Bildquelle]{%
\protect\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
\protect\\*{\protect\scriptsize{}#2}}{%
\protect\\*{\protect\scriptsize{}#1: #2}}}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{table}
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
\textbf{Bezeichnung} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{z} &
$\mathbf{u'_N}$ & $\mathbf{v'_N}$ \\
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F \\
A & B & C & D & E & F \\
A & B & C & D & E & F \\
A & B & C & D & E & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Koordinaten ausgewählter Weißpunkte]%
{\label{Weisspunkte}Koordinaten ausgewählter Weißpunkte%
\FS[Quelle]{[Poy12, S.~279]\index{Illuminant}}}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
\textbf{Bezeichnung} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{z} &
$\mathbf{u'_N}$ & $\mathbf{v'_N}$ \\
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Koordinaten ausgewählter Weißpunkte]%
{\label{Weisspunkte2}Koordinaten ausgewählter Weißpunkte%
\FS[Quelle]{[Poy12, S.~279]\index{Illuminant}}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Looks like:
[image: Part of MWE output]

**Solution** (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518731/182650)

After adding

```
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={sf,bf},position=bottom,singlelinecheck=false]%
{caption}
```

the result for the MWE looks like this, which is OK for me.
[image]

Comment: There is no \\ in your example, so how shall we guess why it doesn't work as expected? Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @Tiuri See the reference right at the start. A MWE will probably take me hours, specifically as it's likely the MWE will not show the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem. I gathered the snippets from this question and the one you link to above, and I get a line break. So, the problem must be somewhere else in your code. For example in the definition for `\Lt` which I could not find.

Comment: If I replace `\Lt{X}` with `X`, it doesn't change the effect (which was expected, because `\Lt` stands for "label table", and effectively it just adds a prefix to the label given: `\newcommand{\Lt}[1]{tab:#1}`).

Comment: @JasperHabicht The issue is "*it works in most cases*", but not all cases. For my tables it failed in 3 out of 7, while for figures the failure rate was even smaller. My guess was that the vertical spacing for the example page is rather tight.

Comment: Then we're not going to be able to reproduce your problem or solve it.  But since you have an example that exhibits the problem, you can trim it down to a MWE.  Move the relevant definitions into the example, and remove the extraneous text.  If vertical spacing is a factor, use `\parbox` to make a box of the correct height.

Comment: Oh, I tried to compile with the `caption` package. As this is what Werner suggested in the answer of the above linked original question, I thought, you would use it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo ??? The caption is below the tables and figures. What are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You can simplify the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption[]{aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa
ccccccccccccccc bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ 
dddddddddddddd}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}

\caption[]{aaaaa\\bbb}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Most classes set captions in two styles, first essentially in an `\mbox` on a single line that is centred if it fits in the text box (and `\\` does not do anything in an mbox). If that box is too wide to fit on a line it is discarded, and the caption i re-set in a `\parbox`, If the second format is used `\\` will work.

The `caption` package has an option to skip the one-line test, if that is what you want here.

Comment: I don't quite see the difference: Do I have to start a paragraph before `\caption`? Reviewing my document I found that most captions are rather long (longer than one line), so they "worked". As it seems my initial suspect was right: If it all fits in one line, it will be forced into one line, regardless of any `\\`. Right?

Comment: @U.Windl as I say if `\mbox{short\\ caption}`  will fit on a line, it is used, and `\\  ` does nothing in a mbox. It is normally best to avoid any use of forced linebreaks, but if you want to do this you can as i say use the caption package and disable the one-line setting.

Comment: the difference in my examples is simply that `aaaaabbb` fits on a line