# conditionals inside newcommand with multiple argument

Tags: macros, conditionals

This question is an extension of [conditionals inside newcommand with empty argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537219/conditionals-inside-newcommand-with-empty-argument)

I have a macro that looks like

```
\newcommand{\pcs}[3]{{#1}_{#2}^{(#3)}}
```

It is the third input where I would like to perform conditionals. If #3 is empty, I want nothing (not even the round brackets).

A desired output for

```
\begin{itemize}
\item $\pcs{a}{b}{c}$
\item $\pcs{a}{b}{}$
\end{itemize}
```

should look like

[image]

Comment: use `etoolbox`, then `\ifblank{#3}{}{^{(#3)}}` might be what you are after. Note that here I'd use `^{\smash{(}#3\smash{)}}` as the `^{(...)}` often gets excessively large and disturbs line spacing.

Comment: You don't need to load `etoolbox` with a reasonable up to date LaTeX installation. You can use `\IfBlankF{#3}{^{(#3)}}` instead.

Comment: @Skillmon I know it had something similar, just could not remember if it was public

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your last argument is only optional you might as well define it as an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand \pcs { m m o } {{#1}_{#2}\IfValueT{#3}{^{(#3)}}}

\begin{document}
$\pcs{a}{b}[c]$ and $\pcs{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really useful and convenient. Thanks a lot!