# Mergedate not working with biblatex-publist?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

I want to add a list of publications to my CV, and I found that the `biblatex-publist` package offers everything I was looking for.

For conference papers, I used the `@misc` entry. I want the entries to appear starting with the `year`, but I want the date to be displayed later in the entry. When using the `authoryear` bibliography style, I can achieve this with `mergedate`.

For the `publist` style, however, this option seems to have no effect, and it begins each entry with the full date. I can use the `date=year` option to suppress the full date at the beginning of the entry, but it then also omits the full date from the entry later.

Is there a way to achieve an output similar to how `mergedate` works with `authoryear`?

MEW:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
  bibstyle=publist, 
  % date=year,
  mergedate=basic, 
  sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
  
\plauthorname[Firstname][]{Lastname}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{publist.bib}

@misc{paper2012test,
author = {Lastname, Firstname},
title = {Paper title},
year = {2012},
howpublished = {Paper presented at the meeting of Organization Name, Location},
date = {2012-11-03},
keywords = {paper}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{publist.bib}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[type=misc, heading=subbibliography, title={Conference Papers (selected)}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my field (CS/NLP) usually `@inproceedings` is used for conference papers, even if the proceedings are not actually officially published - but maybe for your field that is different. That will probably not solve the date issue though, for that maybe use date=year and put the exact date in the howpublished, i.e., _presented at the meeting on 2012-11-03_, or in the note field which is usually displayed last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `publist` uses `authoryear` as base style. It therefore 'inherits' the `mergedate` option. But `publist` has its own date handling that interferes with what `mergedate` can do.

Here is a very rudimentary way to get something similar to `mergedate` to work.

It forces `date=year,` locally by redefining the macros `\printdate` and `\printdateextra` and then do not delete the year for later use if we have a more granular date.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
  bibstyle=publist, 
  mergedate=false,
  sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
  
\plauthorname[Firstname][]{Lastname}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bpl:date:makedate}{%
  \begingroup
  \protected\def\printdate{\csuse{mkdaterangeyear}{}}%
  \protected\def\printdateextra{\csuse{mkdaterangeyearextra}{}}%
    \printtext{%
        \iffieldundef{year}{%
            \iffieldundef{pubstate}%
                {}
                {%
                 \printfield{pubstate}%
                 \if@pubstateextra
                   \printfield{extradate}%
                 \fi%
                }%
        }{%
           \iffieldundef{month}%
                {\printdateextra}%
                {\printdate}%
        }%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

\renewbibmacro*{bpl:year+labelyear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}{%
        \iffieldundef{pubstate}%
            {\let\bbx@lasthash\undefined}%
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:date:labeldate+extradate}%
             \savefield{pubstate}{\bbx@lasthash}%
             \clearfield{pubstate}%
            }%
    }{%
         \usebibmacro{bpl:date:labeldate+extradate}%
         \savefield{year}{\bbx@lasthash}%
         \iffieldundef{month}
           {\clearfield{year}}
           {}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{paper2012test,
  author = {Lastname, Firstname},
  title = {Paper title},
  year = {2012},
  howpublished = {Paper presented at the meeting of Organization Name, Location},
  date = {2012-11-03},
  keywords = {paper},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 2012. Paper title. Paper presented at the meeting of Organization Name, Location. Nov. 3, 2012.]

Comment: This works perfectly for the conference papers. Unfortunately, the `mergedate=false`  option results in empty parentheses in my `@article` entries. I was able to use this solution to fix it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540435/65103