# How to deal with empty values in command arguments

Tags: macros, tex-core, best-practices, arguments

In this MWE, a command argument is directly passed to an environment. That works fine with empty values:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\minipag}[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}[b][#1][b]{6em}
    One minipage
    \end{minipage}
    }
    
\begin{document}

\minipag{2em}
\minipag{\relax}
\minipag{}

\end{document}
```

However, when the argument is passed using a macro, and it takes an empty value, it is not recognized by the (minipage) environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\minipag}[1]{%
    \def\upto{#1}
    \begin{minipage}[b][\upto][b]{6em}
    One minipage
    \end{minipage}
    }
    
\begin{document}

\minipag{2em}
\minipag{\relax}
\minipag{}

\end{document}
```

Why does it happens? What is the way to do this?

For me, the underlying question is what are *string* arguments really: macros, lists of tokens, general text, registers...

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764)

Comment: The answer to the "underlying question" is that tex doesn't have strings, macro arguments, are lists of tokens (as in more or less everything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no general feature here you are just seeing a lack of error checking in minipage.

In

```
\begin{minipage}[b][...][b]{6em}
```

The `...` is a *length* so an empty argument is a syntax error. Unfortunately `minipage` (as space was tight in 1993 when this argument was added) does not do any real error checking and the empty argument sneaks through then finally ends up at

```
\ifx \relax #2\else \setlength \@tempdimb {#2}
```

so the `\ifx` test is a (overly simple) test to see if that argument was used; and when `#2` is empty it does not test `#2` against `\relax` but rather tests `\relax` against `\else` which is a nonsense test which just luckily makes it avoid the setlength with an empty length, so avoids an error.

When `#2` is (any) commandname other than `\relax` then the intended test happens, the test is false so the length is set to the expansion of `#2` which in this case is empty, so you get an error, the same as for

```
\setlegth\@tempdima{}
```

Comment: So, following your explanation, when the argument #1 is empty then "..." is "nothing'". However, \upto seems to be "another kind of nothing''? Is it possible to define \upto to have "the first category of nothing''? Or should I add some code like \ifx\upto\empty\let\upto\relax\fi

Comment: @e_moro no the test that is used here is an `\ifx` test  so it does not use expansion at all so it is testing if you put anything in that argument not what it expands to so you can not put anything that is equivalent to nothing,

Comment: oh sorry I misread your comment:  if you use \relax it might accidentally work but not by any tested or intentional code path. Passing anything other than a valid length into that argument of minipage is a user error, you should raise an error if the argument passed to your macro is not a length.

Comment: I understand the explanation. But my comment (and question) is also about how to deal with such an odd issue. My goal is to write a command that keeps that minipage feature, ie, it can be called with both \minipag {length} or \minipag{}. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @e_moro no you should not keep it or rely on it working, if you want to allow an empty argument, best would be to make the argument of your command _optional_ and if it is not supplied, call minipage without the length argument. If it is supplied then it should be a length and you can pass it on to minipage. If (although I would not recommend it) you want the argument of your command to be mandatory, then check that it is empty  and if it is call minipage without the length argument.

Comment: that is the syntax should be `\minipag[length]` or `\minpag`   not `\minipage{}` that would match other things with optional lengths, like minipage itself, or `\\[2em]` etc,

Comment: Uh-huh, I agree. But (and that is the problem with using MWEs), as my ultimate goal is to define a newcolumntype for tabular, I thought an empty argument like e{} was right. Thanks for all of your support.

Comment: ok then test for empty and use or don't use the minipage optional argument