# What address label package might exist that is compatible with {fancyhdr}?

Tags: tables

I need to produce a club Roster. I was going to use the {labels} package, which permits reading an external file and formatting labels for the roster pages very well.  I had that all worked out.  Problem: I have to put a header on either every page or the odd pages.  \usepackage{labels} and \usepackage{fancyhdr} do not seem to work together, even though the labels package documentation suggests using it for just what I want.  Just putting those 2 packages into the preamble destroys the header. It appears that the labels package will always overwrite the header.

Also, I have investigated building my labels with a tabular environment.  Possible, but the lack of newline in a tabular environment  has caused me to look everywhere before reinventing the wheel. If this isn't clear enough, I can provide a MWE but it isn't the shortest one ever. There is also an older pkg called EnvLab. I couldn't tell if it would make pages of labels with a header or not.

Requirements:

1. Paper size must be 5.5 x 8 inches, printed both sides and intended for booklet. Actual photocopy paper is 5.5 x 8 pre-cut. Printer will print both sides
2. Every right side page except the title page will have  a header containing a logo and the club name(like a banner across the top of the page)
3. Every page except the title page will have a page number.
4. It will have a title page
5. Officers Page - 8 names with linked email addresses.
6. Many pages of members, 6 per page organized in 2 columns - exactly like mailing labels.  Each pair of members is alloted about 13 lines(rows).

A list sorted by boat names - these are not labels

A list sorted by Marina names - these are not labels

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tgtermes} %The TeX Gyre Termes family of fonts is based on the Nimbus Roman family, but heavily extended. Math support is available in OpenType format.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %for unicode

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8in, top=25mm
, left=20mm]{geometry} %for paper size

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{navy}{RGB}{0,0,150}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0, 150, 0}

\usepackage[colorlinks=false,
allbordercolors={0 0 1},
pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{33pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %clear header and footer


\chead{\scalebox{1.5}{ \raisebox{2.5mm}{\color{navy}{Great Sailing Association}}}}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{Swedish_Flag.png}}
\rhead{\scalebox{1.5}{ \raisebox{2.5mm}{\color{navy}{\thepage}}}}


\usepackage{setspace}  %needed for double spacing officers
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %sans serif
\usepackage{helvet}


%DISABLE THIS PACKAGE TO SEE ALL ELSE WORKING
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
%\LabelGridtrue
\LabelCols=2%Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=3%Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftPageMargin=.5in% Gutter
\RightPageMargin=.5in%
\InterLabelRow=0.1in% Gap between rows of labels
\TopPageMargin=25mm%
\BottomPageMargin=5mm% 
\InterLabelColumn=5mm%    Gap between columns of labels


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Start of the document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\begin{center}

        \rmfamily
        \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{Swedish_Flag.png}
        
        \vspace{2\baselineskip}
        \scalebox{8}{\color{navy}{GSA}} 
            \vspace*{1\baselineskip}    
        
        \scalebox{8}{\color{navy}{Roster}}
        
        \vspace*{\fill}
        {\scalebox{2}{\color{navy}{May 2021}}}
        
    \end{center}
    
\end{titlepage}
    

%\vspace*{4\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{\LARGE{}Officers}}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}
\end{center}


{\Large{}Commodore: \href{http://email@gmail.com}{\textcolor{navy}{Adam One}}} 
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}Past Commodore: \href{http://email@gmail.com}{\textcolor{navy}{Adam Two}}}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}Vice Commodore: \href{http://email@gmail.com}{\textcolor{navy}{Robert Three}}}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}Rear Commodore: \href{http://email@gmail.com}{\textcolor{navy}{Tony Four}}}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}Treasurer: \href{http://email@gmail.com}{\textcolor{navy}{Billy Jack}}}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}Portsmouth Captain: \href{http://email@gmail.com}{\textcolor{navy}{David Six}}}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}PHRF Captain: \href{http://email@gmail.com}{\textcolor{navy}{Sarah Seven}}}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}Secretary: \href{http://email@gmail.com}{\textcolor{navy}{Laura Eight}}}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}Senior Member: \href{http://email@gmail.com}{\textcolor{navy}{Evelyn Nine}}}


\pagebreak
{\Large{}Just another page}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}With Two Lines. It should have a header too. But doesn't}
\pagebreak


\begin{labels}  
Ann P Adams
1200 Pine Heights Ave.
Metropolis, TX  21229
Cell: 410-111-3990c
emailaddr@gmail.com
Joined: 1990

Richard \& Sandra Allen III
2120 Tred Avon Rd.
Metropolis, TX  21221
Home: 410-111-3069
Cell: 410-111-6407c
emailaddr@gmail.com
Marina: Home
Boat: DRAGON LADY
Type: Vagabond 47
Joined: 2006

Matthew \& Mary Beaty
13406 Blythenia Rd.
Phoenix, MD  21131
Home: 443-111-6474
Work: 443-111-6474
Cell: 443-111-6474c
emailaddr@gmail.com
Joined: 1986

Chris Bero
5020 Shetland Ct
Metropolis, PA  17050
Home: 717-111-1338
Work: 717-111-1929 x247
Cell: 717-111-0458
emailaddr@gmail.com
email2@gmail.com
Marina: Bowleys Marina
Boat: SEOUL MATES
Type: Hunter 36
Joined: 2015

Barry Bilson
3617 Bay Drive
Metropolis, TX  21220
Home: 410-111-0207
Cell: 410-111-1568c
emailaddr@gmail.com
Marina: Bowleys Marina
Boat: EXPRESSWAVE
Type: Express 30
Joined: 1982

Gregory \& Donna Bincarowsky
2751 Druck Valley Rd.
Metropolis, PA  17406
Work: 717-111-2234
Cell: 717-111-8681c
emailaddr@gmail.com
Marina: Magothy River
Boat: CHAMPAGNE
Type: Catalina 34
Joined: 2004

Joe \& Elaine Borrison
4 Lantern Circle
Parkton, MD  21120
Home: 410-111-9449
Cell: 410-111-5151
emailaddr@gmail.com
Marina: Private Mooring
Boat: TIPSY TURTLE
Type: IC24
Joined: 2017

Brian Bashears
2122 Rosalie Ave
Metropolis, MD  21221
Home: 410-111-5356
Cell: 410-111-5356
emailaddr@gmail.com
Marina: Home
Joined: 2020

Tom \& Alma Brown
122 Union Rd.
Metropolis, PA  19320
Home: 610-111-1372
Cell: 484-111-4825c
emailaddr@gmail.com
Marina: Bowleys Marina
Boat: ORIONS CHILD
Type: Hunter 33.5
Joined: 2001

Tom \& Joann Calvert
115 Shetland Hills Dr.
Metropolis, TX  21093
Home: 410-111-9275
Work: 410-111-4788
Cell: 443-111-5360
emailaddr@gmail.com
Marina: Windy Hill Marina
Boat: STILL a GORILLA
Type: S-2  9.1
Joined: 1977

Chris Carrino
112 Bridgewater Dr
Metropolis, PA  18938
Home: 202-111-3683
emailaddr@gmail.com
Marina: Bowleys Marina
Boat: LEAPFROG
Type: J 30
Joined: 2019

Ed \& Gloria Cilumbrello
1306 3rd Road
Metropolis, TX  21220
Home: 410-111-2181
Work: 410-111-3060
Cell: 410-111-2181c
emailaddr@gmail.com
Marina: Wilson Point Mens Club
Boat: CARROT
Type: Mull 46 Custom
Joined: 1985




\end{labels}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End of the document contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: A MWe as well as a sketch of the expected output would be rella helpful here. Please include them. Regarding "lack of newline in a tabular environment": there certainly are ways to achiece automtic or manual linebreaks inside of table cells. What to use in your case depends on the kind of output you want to achieve.

Comment: OK. I will put an MWE. Do i use the Code tab in the question to add that?  I haven't done this before.

Comment: Just edit your question and add the code directly into the text. You can then highlight/select the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) in order to make sure it is [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192).

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Since points 6, 7 and 8 all mentions somwhow sorted lists and you also previously mentioned "permits reading an external file":Do you create the sorted lists manually or are they created with the help of a different application? If so, does this application already sort the lists for you or does this application just generate an external file that you then want to use to generate your lists inside of your booklet?

Comment: The sorted lists as well as the labels, I make in Excel, since that is where the original data is.  I program in VBA and an  assortment of other languages so getting the data into nearly any format is easy-ish.  The {labels} package here allows reading from an external file.  That will be easiest when I try to teach club members to maintain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option with [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool) since you keep your member list in Excel (and can export it to CSV):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=5.5in,
  paperheight=8in,
  margin=25mm,
  left=20mm]
  {geometry} %for paper size

\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\definecolor{navy}{RGB}{0,0,150}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0, 150, 0}

\usepackage[
  colorlinks=false,
  allbordercolors={0 0 1},
  pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}]
  {hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %clear header and footer

\setlength{\headheight}{36pt}% To accommodate for the tall header (picture)
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}}
\fancyhead[C]{\scalebox{1.5}{\color{navy}{Great Sailing Association}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\scalebox{1.5}{\color{navy}{\thepage}}}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{officers.csv}
title,name,email
Commodore,Adam One,adam1@cares.com
Past Commodore,Adam Two,adam2@whocares.com
Vice Commodore,Robert Three,robert3@whocares.com
Rear Commodore,Tony Four,tony4@whocares.com
Treasurer,Billy Jack,billyjack@whocares.com
Portsmouth Captain,David Six,david6@whocares.com
PHRF Captain,Sarah Seven,sarah7@whocares.com
Secretary,Laura Eight,laura8@whocares.com
Senior Member,Evelyn Nine,evelyn9@whocares.com
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{members.csv}
name,address,city,state,zipcode,home,work,mobile,emailA,emailB,marina,boat,type,joined
Adam One,123 Random Rd, Randomville,RN,12345,123-456-7890,456-789-0123,789-012-3456,adam1@whocares.com,adamone@whocares.com,Marina Adam,Dragon Lady,Vagabond 1,2006
Adam Two,456 Random Rd, Randomville,RN,23456,123-456-7890,456-789-0123,789-012-3456,adam2@whocares.com,adamone@whocares.com,Marina Adam,Dragon Sir,Vagabond 2,2007
Robert Three,789 Random Rd, Randomville,RN,34567,123-456-7890,456-789-0123,789-012-3456,robert3@whocares.com,robertthree@whocares.com,Marina Robert,Dragon Madam,Vagabond 3,2008
Tony Four,1234 Random Rd, Randomville,RN,45678,123-456-7890,456-789-0123,789-012-3456,tony4@whocares.com,tonyfour@whocares.com,Marina Tony,Dragon Justice,Vagabond 4,2009
Billy Jack,2345 Random Rd, Randomville,RN,56789,123-456-7890,456-789-0123,789-012-3456,billyjack@whocares.com,,Marina Billy,Dragon Kid,Vagabond Jack,2010
David Six,3456 Random Rd, Randomville,RN,67890,123-456-7890,456-789-0123,789-012-3456,david6@whocares.com,davidsix@whocares.com,Marina David,Dragon Child,Vagabond 5,2011
Sarah Seven,4567 Random Rd, Randomville,RN,98765,123-456-7890,456-789-0123,789-012-3456,sarah7@whocares.com,sarahseven@whocares.com,Marina Sarah,Dragon Sister,Vagabond 6,2012
Laura Eight,5678 Random Rd, Randomville,RN,87654,123-456-7890,456-789-0123,789-012-3456,laura8@whocares.com,lauraeight@whocares.com,Marina Laura,Dragon Brother,Vagabond 7,2013
Evelyn Nine,6789 Random Rd, Randomville,RN,76543,123-456-7890,456-789-0123,789-012-3456,evelyn9@whocares.com,evelynnine@whocares.com,Marina Evelyn,Dragon Parent,Vagabond 8,2014
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\printofficers}{%
  \DTLloaddb{officers}{officers.csv}% Load officers database
  \DTLforeach{officers}{% Process officers database
    \Title=title,
    \Name=name,
    \Email=email%
  }{%
    \par\addvspace{.5\baselineskip}
    \Large\Title: \href{mailto:\Email}{\color{navy}\strut\Name}\par
  }
}

\newcounter{membercount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setifexist}[1]{%
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/5764
  \expandafter\if\expandafter\relax\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\printmembers}{%
  \DTLloaddb{members}{members.csv}% Load member database
  \setcounter{membercount}{0}% Reset member counter
  \DTLforeach{members}{%
    \Name=name,
    \Address=address,
    \City=city,
    \State=state,
    \Zipcode=zipcode,
    \Home=home,
    \Work=work,
    \Mobile=mobile,
    \EmailA=emailA,
    \EmailB=emailB,
    \Marina=marina,
    \Boat=boat,
    \Type=type,
    \Joined=joined%
  }{%
    \small
    \stepcounter{membercount}% New member
    \ifodd\value{membercount}
      \par\addvspace{.5\baselineskip}
    \fi
    \makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l }
        \Name \\
        \Address \\
        \City, \State~\Zipcode \\
        \setifexist{\Home}{Home: \Home \\}{}
        \setifexist{\Work}{Work: \Work \\}{}
        \setifexist{\Mobile}{Cell: \Mobile \\}{}
        \setifexist{\EmailA}{\href{mailto:\EmailA}{\EmailA} \\}{}
        \setifexist{\EmailB}{\href{mailto:\EmailB}{\EmailB} \\}{}
        Marina: \Marina \\
        Boat: \Boat \\
        Type: \Type \\
        Joined: \Joined
      \end{tabular}}%
  }
}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{-1}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
  \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  \scalebox{8}{\color{navy}{GSA}} 
  \vspace*{\baselineskip}    

  \scalebox{8}{\color{navy}{Roster}}

  \vspace*{\fill}
  {\scalebox{2}{\color{navy}{May 2021}}}

\end{center}
    
\clearpage

\begin{center}
  \bfseries\LARGE\color{blue}Officers
\end{center}

\addvspace{\baselineskip}

\printofficers

\clearpage

{\Large Just another page}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

{\Large With Two Lines.}

\clearpage

\printmembers

\end{document}
```

I've written the CSV's verbatim in my example as `officers.csv` and `members.csv`, but you will have these stored elsewhere, so won't need that code.

Comment: Got it. I'll try this too.  I had previously looked at datatool before posting this question and that is where i was going next.

Comment: This worked well.  Just prep the data to remove special characters and replace with \&, \#, \_  etc.

Comment: @Narlin: There are options within [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool) to accommodate for special characters so you don't have to do that. Read about `\DTLloadrawdb` within the [`datatool` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/datatool).

Comment: So yeah.  That was a 2 times by 3 letter trivial change to the tex file which saves about 10 lines of VBA code, plus not having to explain it to anyone. cool! Just change \DTLloaddb to \DTLloadrawdb in both uses.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could combine the packages `multicol`, `csvsimple` and `pgffor` in order to produce the list of members. To compile the document, you need 4 csv files, named `member1.csv`, `member2.csv`,... Each csv file contains all the information of one member, files are numbered in the order in which you want the corresponding entries to appear in the booklet. The cvs files should contain `&` instead of `\&` and `{,}` intead of `,`.

In the following MWE, I additionally tried to simplify the code that is used in the officers page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tgtermes} %The TeX Gyre Termes family of fonts is based on the Nimbus Roman family, but heavily extended. Math support is available in OpenType format.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %for unicode

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8in, top=25mm
, left=20mm]{geometry} %for paper size

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{navy}{RGB}{0,0,150}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0, 150, 0}

\usepackage[colorlinks=false,
allbordercolors={0 0 1},
pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{36pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %clear header and footer


\chead{\scalebox{1.5}{ \raisebox{2.5mm}{\color{navy}{Great Sailing Association}}}}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}}
\rhead{\scalebox{1.5}{ \raisebox{2.5mm}{\color{navy}{\thepage}}}}


\usepackage{setspace}  %needed for double spacing officers
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %sans serif
\usepackage{helvet}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\officer}[3]{{\Large{}#1: \href{#2}{\textcolor{navy}{#3}}} 
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\begin{center}

        \rmfamily
        \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
        
        \vspace{2\baselineskip}
        \scalebox{8}{\color{navy}{GSA}} 
            \vspace*{1\baselineskip}    
        
        \scalebox{8}{\color{navy}{Roster}}
        
        \vspace*{\fill}
        {\scalebox{2}{\color{navy}{May 2021}}}
        
    \end{center}
    
\end{titlepage}
    

%\vspace*{4\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{\LARGE{}Officers}}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}
\end{center}

\officer{Commodore}{http://email@gmail.com}{Adam One}

\officer{Past Commodore}{http://email@gmail.com}{Adam Two}

\officer{Vice Commodore}{http://email@gmail.com}{Robert Three}


\pagebreak
{\Large{}Just another page}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

{\Large{}With Two Lines. It should have a header too. But doesn't}
\pagebreak

\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}
\foreach \ii in {1,...,4} {
\csvautotabular[respect and]{member\ii.csv}
\bigskip

}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks quite promising.  Give me half a day to digest it.  I'll get back midday tomorrow. n.

Comment: Even though i will use the datatool method, this works well.  Only reason to go the other way is that this creates a few extra files which tend to clutter my small mind.  But I up voted and learned a lot.