# Remove space when argument is empty in bespoke citation command

Tags: spacing, citing, natbib, citetalias

I am trying to define a bespoke citation command which mimics the behaviour of `\citep[][]{}` but for the case when I am using some citation alias, e.g. when the author is an institution and I want its acronym.

The problem I have is that, when there is no text *after* the citation, Latex is still displaying a space between the year and the closing parenthesis. I have tried defining a `\checkEmpty` command based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53091/104780) but to no avail.

My code is below:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\defcitealias{BCBS2011}{BCBS}
\newcommand{\checkEmpty}[1]{
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax{\ignorespaces}\else{#1}\fi
}
\newcommand{\mycitepalias}[3]{
    \citepalias[#2][\citeyear{#1}\checkEmpty{#3}]{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\mycitepalias{BCBS2011}{}{}\\
\mycitepalias{BCBS2011}{with text before}{}\\
\mycitepalias{BCBS2011}{with text before}{and after}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

The output is displayed below. As you can see in the first and second line, there is an undesirable space.

[image]

**PS**: As a bonus, I would like to add a comma after the date in case there is text after the citation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `{\ignorespaces}` does nothing, because `\ignorespaces` is anyway followed by `}`. But it's irrelevant nonetheless.

You are adding spaces by not protecting endlines.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{BCBS2011,
  author={{Basel Committee on Bank Supervision}},
  title={Basel {III}: {A} global regulatory framework for
         more resilient banks and banking system},
  year=2011,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\defcitealias{BCBS2011}{BCBS}
\newcommand{\checkEmpty}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \ #1%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\mycitepalias}[3]{%
    \citepalias[#2][\citeyear{#1}\checkEmpty{#3}]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\mycitepalias{BCBS2011}{}{}

\mycitepalias{BCBS2011}{with text before}{}

\mycitepalias{BCBS2011}{with text before}{and after}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had tried adding `%`... but at the wrong place that is after `\relax` instead of the very beginning of the command. Cheers.