# Use of \ifmtarg yields spurious space

Tags: spacing

I seem to be getting a spurious space from `\@ifmtarg`.  The MWE below yields the image on the left where there is an spurious space before the end of the `hyperref` (for the last two cases).  However, if I add an `\unskip` hack I obtain the desired result on the right hand side.

[image]
[image]

### Notes:

- A simple use case of `\@ifmtarg` did not reproduce this problem for me so perhaps it has something to do with the way I am using it.
- The MWE below is going to raise some WTF questions as to why I am using `\renewcommand` but this is a greatly simplified version from my actual use case, and probably can do with a lot of code clean up. But for now, this is the structure I have.

### References:

- [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co/53079#53079)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\IfIsEmptyArg}[3]{\@ifmtarg{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\SetTitle}[1]{}


\newcommand{\ExtractAndSetTitle}[2]{% 
    % #1 = macro csname in which the result is stored
    % #2 = text of title witout symbol
    \renewcommand{\SetTitle}[1]{%
        %\latexglobal\expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname{%
        % Simplify above for this MWE.
        \expandafter\gdef\csname #1\endcsname{%
            ##1%
            \IfIsEmptyArg{\Symbol}{}{~\Symbol}% 
            %\unskip% Hack!!!!
        }%
    }%
    \SetTitle{#2}%
}% 


\begin{document}
\def\Symbol{$\times$}%  This works
\ExtractAndSetTitle{ExtractedTitle}{Times}%
\href{some.pdf}{\ExtractedTitle}%

\def\Symbol{\empty}%          This requires \unskip HACK
\ExtractAndSetTitle{ExtractedTitle}{Times}%
\href{some.pdf}{\ExtractedTitle}%

\def\Symbol{}%          This requires \unskip HACK
\ExtractAndSetTitle{ExtractedTitle}{Times}%
\href{some.pdf}{\ExtractedTitle}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like an expansion issue. I don't know `\@ifmtarg`, but either you are using it wrong or it has a bug. In your MWE, `\IfIsEmptyArg` is evaluating to false, and the space is due to the `~` (while `\empty` and `{}` are invisible of course). Just replace `~` by `!` and it will become obvious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *are* using `\@ifmtarg` incorrectly. Here's a short example that shows your incorrect use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ifmtarg
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
Test 1: \@ifmtarg{}{YES}{NO} \par
Test 2: \@ifmtarg{ }{YES}{NO} \par
Test 3: \@ifmtarg{\empty}{YES}{NO} \par
Test 4: \@ifmtarg{\relax}{YES}{NO} \par
Test 5: \@ifmtarg{\@empty}{YES}{NO}
\end{document}
```

From the above `\empty`, `\relax` and `\@empty` are all considered not empty. Of course, you could use another method, like setting it in a box and testing whether it's width is non-zero:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@ifmtarg}[1]
  {\setbox1=\hbox{\ignorespaces#1}\ifdim\wd1>\z@\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
Test 1: \@ifmtarg{}{YES}{NO} \par
Test 2: \@ifmtarg{ }{YES}{NO} \par
Test 3: \@ifmtarg{\empty}{YES}{NO} \par
Test 4: \@ifmtarg{\relax}{YES}{NO} \par
Test 5: \@ifmtarg{\@empty}{YES}{NO}
\end{document}
```

I guess it depends on your use case. If you don't have anything special but just want to test whether the contents of what is supplied is empty, then the above should work.

Comment: Both `\def\Symbol{\empty}` and `\def\Symbol{}` yield identical results, where `\Symbol` is what is being checked. Seems like an expansion issue then.

Comment: After further testing this works. So back to the same solution as my earlier question on [proper way to detect empty/blank text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44919/proper-way-to-detect-empty-blank-text). Was trying to use `\@ifmtarg` as I thought it was more lightweight and did not have to deal with any side effects of executing the code twice. Oh well... Still very much appreciated though.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `\@ifmtarg` is evaluating `\Symbol` as not empty, probably because it is not expanding it. Whether it should or not, I have no idea.

The following code shows what's happening:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}

\begin{document}

\def\Symbol{}
\makeatletter
\@ifmtarg{\Symbol}{\tt\string\Symbol{} is empty}{\tt\string\Symbol{} is not empty}%  
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

as it yields:

> \Symbol is not empty

From there, your code outputs `~\Symbol`, causing an empty space due to the `~`.

If one expansion of `\Symbol` is enough (i.e., `\Symbol` expands directly to its content, not to other macros/commands which themselves might expand to an empty string), then the following test with `\expandafter` works:

```
\expandafter\@ifmtarg\expandafter{\Symbol}{...}{...}%
```

One possible way to deal with more expansions would be to fully expand `\Symbol` (with an `\edef`) into a temporary variable, say `\SymbolExpanded`, and then run the above test on `\SymbolExpanded`.

Comment: This clarifies where the space is coming from. Now, just need to figure out how to get `\Symbol` expanded.

Comment: @PeterGrill If one expansion is enough, the following does the trick in my example code: `\expandafter\@ifmtarg\expandafter{\Symbol}{...}{...}`. Another option would be to put the `~` inside `\Symbol`, i.e. add it to the definition of `\Symbol` whenever you define it to something "not empty".

Comment: Yep, that expansion magic works for the `\def\Symbol{}` case, which is more important.  Please update the answer with that.

Comment: @PeterGrill Done :)

Answer (score 3):

`\@ifmtarg` considers empty only an argument consisting of zero or more spaces. In your case the argument is always `\Symbol`, which is definitely non empty.

Let's see what `\@ifmtarg{\Symbol}{E}{N}` does. Here's the definition of `\@ifmtarg`:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\Q=3
\long\gdef\@ifmtarg#1{\@xifmtarg#1QQ\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo\@nil}
\long\gdef\@xifmtarg#1#2Q#3#4#5\@nil{#4}
\endgroup
```

The first expansion does

```
\@xifmtarg\SymbolQQ\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo\@nil{E}{N}
```

Thus the arguments for `\@xifmtarg` are:

- `#1` is `\Symbol` (`#1` is not delimited)
- `#2` is empty (`#2` is everything up to the first `Q`<sub>3</sub>
- `#3` is `Q`<sub>3</sub>
- `#4` is `\@secondoftwo`
- `#5` is `\@firstoftwo` (everything up to `\@nil`).

Therefore the next expansion is

```
\@secondoftwo{E}{N}
```

which returns `N`. If the argument to `\@ifmtarg` had been any sequence of spaces, they would be gobbled because TeX ignores space tokens when looking for an undelimited argument. So with `\@ifmtarg{}{E}{N}` we'd get

- `#1` is `Q`<sub>3</sub> (the first non space token)
- `#2` is empty (`#2` is everything up to the first following `Q`<sub>3</sub>
- `#3` is `\@secondoftwo`
- `#4` is `\@firstoftwo`
- `#5` is empty (everything up to `\@nil`).

so that the next step would be `\@firstoftwo{E}{N}` and then `E`.

You probably want

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfIsEmptyArg}[3]{%
  \expandafter\@ifmtarg\expandafter{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\makeatother
```

so you look at the expansion of `\Symbol` rather than to `\Symbol`. Of course, with `\def\Symbol{\empty}`, the “non empty” branch would be followed.