# Testing for "emptiness"

Tags: macros, conditionals

Sometimes, in LaTeX one wants to do the simple test if a macro is empty, e.g.

```
\def\foo{%
  This is...
  \ifx\baz\@empty
    Sparta!
  \else
    a pony farm.
  \fi
}
```

I am interested in how the definition of `\baz` has to be made in order to obtain the desired results. A few thoughts make evident that all of the three definitions

```
\def\baz{}
\edef\baz{\@empty}
\let\baz=\@empty
```

will lead to the true case. Now, I would like to know, what is the best practice, or if there aren't any differences (as far as `\def\@empty{}`), or if there are cases in which one is to favor, (obviously) depending on what one is doing? (Examples would be really nice!)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of earlier questions eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co   or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44919/proper-way-to-detect-empty-blank-text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are asking about the definition (rather than about the form of the test which is the focus of earlier questions)

then assuming `\@empty` has its usual meaning

```
\def\baz{}
\edef\baz{\@empty}
```

are identical in terms of the resulting definition of `\baz`.

```
\let\baz=\@empty
```

is in theory slightly different as TeX can share the memory used to store both definitions but as the definition in this case is empty, that isn't really a difference and in any case the difference is not detectable within TeX.

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for, and also what i was afraid of. So you are basically saying that all the definitions in the end are equivalent (with a negliable difference). Hence one has the free choice. Thank you though for dealing with it.