# Ifthen statement with array value as an entry

Tags: arrays, ifthenelse

Whenever I try to use an element of an array as an entry for a `\ifthenelse` statement I get the error `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 6`. Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{arrayjob, ifthen}
\newarray\items
\begin{document}
\items(0)={item}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\items(0)}{item}}{they're equal}{they're different}
\end{document}
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Never use `arrayjob` with LaTeX, but `arrayjobx`; anyway, `\ifthenelse` does no expansion of its arguments, so it compares the tokens `\items(0)` and `item`, which are different.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Yes, but not with `arrayjob(x)`

Comment: What package should I look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a reimplementation of `\ifthenelse` along the lines of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467527/4427 and a couple of array management macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest \tl_if_blank_p:n
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \xxifthen_legacy_conditional:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \use:c { if#1 } \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean \xxifthen_legacy_conditional_p:n

% implementing arrays
\NewDocumentCommand{\newarray}{mO{,}m}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = separator, #3 = items
  \seq_new:c { l_array_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_array_#1_seq } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\get}{mm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = index
  \seq_item:cn { l_array_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newarray{items}{
  item,
  another,
  OK
}

\begin{document}

\xifthenelse{\streqtest{\get{items}{1}}{item}}{they're equal}{they're different}

\xifthenelse{\streqtest{\get{items}{2}}{item}}{they're equal}{they're different}

\xifthenelse{\streqtest{\get{items}{5*2-7}}{OK}}{they're equal}{they're different}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even use expressions in the second argument to `\get`.

If your array items contain commas, you can change the separator at runtime, for instance

```
\newarray{commas}[|]{
  abc,def |
  xy |
  end,end
}
```

This way item 1 will be `abc,def`.

Comment: I realised that in my code I only need to check whether the array element is empty or not, so I ended up using your code from [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42280/expand-away-empty-macros-within-ifthenelse] and it works fine.