# How can I get the theorem name when using cleveref?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, thmtools

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{ \IfEmptyTF }{ m m m }
  {
    \sbox0{#1}
    \ifdim\wd0=0pt
      #2
    \else
      #3
    \fi
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  postheadspace=.5em,
  headpunct={},
  notebraces={}{},
  notefont=\bfseries,
  headformat=\IfEmptyTF{\NOTE}{\NAME~\NUMBER}{\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE}
]{theorem}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[
  style=theorem,
  name=Theorem
]{theorem}

\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[label=thm:a]
  A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[name=Important theorem, label=thm:b]
  Another theorem.
\end{theorem}

\cref{thm:a} and \cref{thm:b} % <-- should be 'Theorem 1 and Important theorem'

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I'd like to modify the content of `\crefname{theorem}{..}{..}` so that `\cref{..}` prints `Theorem n` if the nth theorem doesn't have a name, but if it does it just prints the name.

I know it can probably be done using `\nameref` or `\autoref`, but is a `\cref` only solution possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is doable using the `cleveref` machinery, because `\crefformat` doesn't seem to have access to the label. Moreover, `cleveref` is designed to be able to combine several numbered items while not repeating the item type (e.g., “theorems 1, 3 and 10”), which doesn't fit very well with what you want to do (articles would need to be added...).

That being said, one can redefine `\cref` to:

- detect if the argument consists of only one label;
- if this is the case and if it has a name recorded by the `nameref` package, retrieve this name and print it (I use the great `refcount` package for this);
- otherwise, let the normal `\cref` command handle the situation.

Unrelated: your dimension test in `\IfEmptyTF` is a bit weird. I reimplemented it in a better way,<sup>1</sup> but it may be that you'd rather want to test whether the first-level expansion of the first argument of `\IfEmptyTF` is empty. It's easy to do, but I kept the principle of “boxing + dimension test” in case this matters for your real life documents.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \IfEmptyTF } { m }
  {
    \hbox_set:Nw \l_tmpa_box #1 \hbox_set_end:
    \dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } = { \c_zero_dim }
    % The T and F clauses are taken from what follows in the input stream
  }

% Save the original \cref commmand
\LetLtxMacro{\__noibe_orig_cref:n}{\cref}

\tl_new:N \l__noibe_theorem_name_tl

\RenewDocumentCommand{ \cref }{ m }
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \clist_count:n {#1} } > { 1 }
      { \__noibe_orig_cref:n {#1} }
      {
        \exp_args:NNo \tl_set:No \l__noibe_theorem_name_tl
          { \getrefbykeydefault {#1} { name } { } }
        \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__noibe_theorem_name_tl
          { \__noibe_orig_cref:n {#1} }
          { \l__noibe_theorem_name_tl }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  postheadspace=.5em,
  headpunct={},
  notebraces={}{},
  notefont=\bfseries,
  headformat=\IfEmptyTF{\NOTE}{\NAME~\NUMBER}{\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE}
]{theorem}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[
  style=theorem,
  name=Theorem
]{theorem}

\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[label=thm:a]
  A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[name=Important theorem, label=thm:b]
  Another theorem.
\end{theorem}

\cref{thm:a} and \cref{thm:b} % “Theorem 1 and Important theorem”

\cref{thm:a,thm:b}            % “Theorems 1 and 2”

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Problematic example for your `\IfEmptyTF`

Here is a simple example where my implementation of `\IfEmptyTF` works fine whereas yours produces an error:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{ \YourIfEmptyTF }{ m m m }
  {
    \sbox0{#1}
    \ifdim\wd0=0pt
      #2
    \else
      #3
    \fi
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \MyIfEmptyTF } { m }
  {
    \hbox_set:Nw \l_tmpa_box #1 \hbox_set_end:
    \dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } = { \c_zero_dim }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%\YourIfEmptyTF{}{\textbf}{\textit}{foo bar} % Error: Too many }'s.

\MyIfEmptyTF{}{\textbf}{\textit}{foo bar} % 'foo bar' is typeset in bold

\MyIfEmptyTF{non-empty}{\textbf}{\textit}{foo bar} % 'foo bar' is typeset in italics

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Footnote**

1. No risk of expanding the start of `#2` when reading the second ⟨dimen⟩ and, more importantly, allow each of the *T* and *F* clauses to act on tokens that follow the `\IfEmptyTF{...}{T}{F}` in the input stream (with your code, `#2` is followed by `\else` in the input stream, and `#3` is followed by `\fi`, which can be a showstopper when you want to implement certain things—this is demonstrated under *Problematic example for your `\IfEmptyTF`* in this answer).

Comment: I didn't think about how it should behave with multiple references, I guess in that case I'd just do it by hand (`\cref{thm:a}` and `\cref{thm:b}`). Btw, I must admit I copied the implementation of `\IfEmptTF` from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42284/172923) post.

Comment: You copied the implementation from egreg's post, but 1) you put it after `ExplSyntaxOn`, which **changes the meaning of spaces** (in egreg's post, TeX will see a space token after `=0pt` which is definitely desirable; in the code from your question, it won't, which is why the first token of `#2` will be expanded and possibly more, regardless of whether the outcome of the test is true or false. 2) In egreg's post, the *then* and *else* clauses are hardcoded in the command and written this way, won't try to read any of the `\else` and `\fi` tokens.

Comment: Your `\IfEmptyTF` command instead grabs these clauses as arguments, thus one can expect them to contain anything. It would work for self-contained *then* and *else* clauses, but if you want to use something that grabs one or more arguments or simply looks ahead in the input, and the arguments or interesting input are *after* the `\IfEmptyTF{...}{T}{F}` code, then you'll need “my” technique with `\use_i:nn` and `\use_ii:nn` (which correspond to `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` in LaTeX2e).

Comment: A silly example to help you understand what I mean could be `\IfEmptyTF{whatever}{\textbf}{\textit}{⟨text that should be set in bold or in italics⟩}`. With your technique, `\textbf` woul be applied to `\else` and `\textit` to `\fi`. With mine, the selected command will be applied to ⟨text that should be set in bold or in italics⟩. Bottom line: `\ifdim` is a TeX primitive; you need to know a bit how it works to avoid pitfalls. TeX conditionals don't work like conditionals in general-purpose programming languages.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a concrete example where my implementation of `\IfEmptyTF` works fine whereas yours produces an error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out later.

Comment: Okay, no problem. In case you wonder, I removed `\use_i:nn` and `\use_ii:nn` from my implementation of `\IfEmptyTF`; the behavior is exactly the same as before, but a bit more efficient. And if you understand how it works, you'll understand why TeX is different from most programming languages, due to the fact that it is a *macro language* (when expanded, a macro grabs its arguments and is replaced by its replacement text, with the arguments substituted for the respective parameters in the replacement text).