# Test for substring with expl3 in argument of \setlength

Tags: expl3, lengths, strings

I want to test if a string contains a substring. I finded good answers in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/check-if-a-string-contains-a-given-character). But I encounter a problem with the first answer of egreg using expl3 and I don't get the same problem with Werner's answer. The problem comes when I use the macro in `\setlength` (I got a 'Missing number, treated' as zero error). I would like to know why and if it can be adapt. I got the same error with Werner's answer buy putting `\protect` before `\instring`. Is `\instring` fragile and `\instringTF` robust? Is it the reason why one works and the other don't? I may be completly wrong about that. I'm kind of suprise that the problem would come from the robust one, I tought it was usually the other way around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

%egreg answer
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\instringTF}{mmmm}
{%
  \oleks_instring:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}%
\tl_new:N \l__oleks_instring_test_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \oleks_instring:nnnn
{%
  \tl_set:Nn \l__oleks_instring_test_tl {#1}
  \regex_match:nnTF {\u{l__oleks_instring_test_tl}}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

%Werner answer
\newcommand{\instring}[4]{%
  \ifnum\pdfmatch{#1}{#2}=1
    #3%
  \else
    #4%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

The sky is \instringTF{str}{string}{blue}{green}. %working
The sky is \instring{str}{string}{blue}{green}.\\ %working

With instringTF (expl3) from egreg:
\begin{itemize}
  %\setlength{\itemsep}{\instringTF{str}{string}{1cm}{2cm}}   %not working
  \item first item
  \item second item
\end{itemize}

With instring (pdfmatch) from Werner:
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\instring{str}{string}{1cm}{2cm}}    %working
  \item first item
  \item second item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There has been discussion about using `\pdfmatch` in `expl3`, but at the end it was decided not to employ it, because it has nonstandard syntax and is not implemented in all TeX engines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of `\setlength` is supposed to be readable as a ⟨glue⟩ according to TeX's grammar. A ⟨glue⟩ is read by TeX using *expansion only,* therefore any command used there must be “expandable”<sup>1</sup> (and the end result of recursive expansion must be a ⟨glue⟩). [Werner's technique](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446691/73317) relies on TeX's `\ifnum` and pdfTeX's `\pdfmatch` primitives, both of which satisfy this constraint, whereas [egreg's technique](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26873/73317) uses `\tl_set:Nn` and `\regex_match:nnTF`, none of which is expandable (using the analogy from the TeXbook, they both use low-level commands that need to be processed in TeX's stomach, as opposed to its mouth).

It is possible, however, to split egreg's command into two parts: one that requires expansion + execution (i.e., mouth + stomach); the other which only requires expansion (what happens in TeX's mouth). In the code below:

- The former is called `\testIfInString` and performs the actual substring test. It can't be used in expansion-only contexts, such as in the second argument of `\setlength`, but you can usually find a suitable place before where it will work just fine.
- The latter is fully expandable and simply chooses the correct branch according to the outcome of the last use of `\testIfInString`. This second command is called `\ifInStringTF`, and I provide variants `\ifInStringT` and `\ifInStringF` for your comfort. `\ifInStringTF`, `\ifInStringT` and `\ifInStringF` are safe to use in expansion-only contexts, such as: in the second argument of `\setlength`, in the second argument of `\setcounter`, after `\if`, `\ifcat`  `\ifnum`, `\ifdim`, `\ifodd`, `\ifcase`, `\number`, `\romannumeral`, inside the replacement text of an `\edef` or an `\xdef`, and many other places.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multicol}           % only for the demo code

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \testIfInString } { m m }
  {
    \oleks_test_if_in_string:nn {#1} {#2}
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \ifInStringTF } { }
  { \oleks_if_in_string:TF }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \ifInStringT } { }
  { \oleks_if_in_string:T }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \ifInStringF } { }
  { \oleks_if_in_string:F }

\tl_new:N \l__oleks_instring_test_tl
\bool_new:N \l__oleks_is_in_string_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \oleks_test_if_in_string:nn
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__oleks_instring_test_tl {#1}
    \regex_match:nnTF { \u{l__oleks_instring_test_tl} } {#2}
      { \bool_set_true:N \l__oleks_is_in_string_bool }
      { \bool_set_false:N \l__oleks_is_in_string_bool }
  }

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \oleks_if_in_string: { T, F, TF } % you can also add 'p'
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__oleks_is_in_string_bool
      { \prg_return_true: }
      { \prg_return_false: }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\testIfInString{str}{string}%
The sky is \ifInStringTF{blue}{green}. \ifInStringT{A}\ifInStringF{B}.
\testIfInString{foobar}{string}%
The sky is not \ifInStringTF{blue}{green}. \ifInStringT{A}\ifInStringF{B}.

With \verb|\setlength|:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns % we don't want the first column material to be stretched
\begin{itemize}
  \testIfInString{str}{string}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\ifInStringTF{1cm}{2cm}}
  \item first item
  \item second item
\end{itemize}

\columnbreak
\begin{itemize}
  \testIfInString{not in 'string'}{string}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\ifInStringTF{1cm}{2cm}}
  \item first item
  \item second item
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Improvement of Werner's `\instring` macro

For reasons that I explained [yesterday](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566510/73317), should you decide for Werner's approach, I recommend to use a modified version of his `\instring` macro. The modified version is called `\MyInString` in the following example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% From Werner in <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446691/73317>
\newcommand{\instring}[4]{%
  % \instring{<pattern>}{<string>}{<true>}{<false>}
  %   pattern = sought after string
  %   string  = string to search
  \ifnum\pdfmatch{#1}{#2}=1
    #3%
  \else
    #4%
  \fi
}

\makeatletter
% I suggest this instead
\newcommand{\MyInString}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdfmatch{#1}{#2}=1
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mystring}{abcdef}

\instring{a}{abcdef}{Yes}{No} \MyInString{a}{abcdef}{Yes}{No}% Yes

\instring{abc}{\mystring}{Yes}{No} \MyInString{abc}{\mystring}{Yes}{No}% Yes

\instring{acb}{\mystring}{Yes}{No} \MyInString{acb}{\mystring}{Yes}{No}% No

\medskip
%\instring{cde}{abcdef}{\textbf}{\textit}{some text}% ERROR: Too many }'s.
%\instring{zzz}{abcdef}{\textbf}{\textit}{other text}% ERROR: Too many }'s.
\MyInString{cde}{abcdef}{\textbf}{\textit}{some text} % bold
\MyInString{zzz}{abcdef}{\textbf}{\textit}{other text}% italics

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the two approaches are semantically very different: with `\regex_match:nnTF { \u{l__oleks_instring_test_tl} } ...`, one performs a precise substring test (where “string” is really “token list”). The tokens in `\l__oleks_instring_test_tl` have to match *exactly,* one by one, for the test to be successful. In contrast to this, the method based on `\ifnum\pdfmatch{#1}{#2}=1` performs a *regular expression match:* `#1` is interpreted as a POSIX extended regular expression. This implies that, for instance, `\MyInString{(abc)+de}{zzabcabcabcdef}{yes}{no}` expands to `yes` because in `zzabcabcabcdef`, there is `abc` one or more times, immediately followed by `de`.

---

**Footnote**

1. One sometimes says “fully expandable” for the same thing.