# Typesetting one symbolic coord differently than the others

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In my plots, I have one bar (labelled `dummy` below) whose tick label needs to be typeset differently. Here's my current attempt (and minimal example), which doesn't quite work yet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  symbolic x coords={foo,bar,dummy},
  xtick=data,
  xticklabel={\ifdefstrequal{\tick}{dummy}{\textcolor{gray}{\tick}}{\tick}}]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (foo,2)
    (bar,4)
    (dummy,3)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I definitely need matching on the `symbolic x coords` name; comparing the `\ticknum` is unfortunately not an option, as the position of the `dummy` bar changes from plot to plot, and I don't want to touch the definition of `xticklabel` each time. So is there a way to do an appropriate string comparison with `\tick`?

Comment: In your actual application, will you provide your data as `coordinates`, or do they come in a file/table?

Comment: I'm using `coordinates`. If the solution would work for `table` too, however, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `ifthen` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  symbolic x coords={foo,bar,dummy},
  xtick=data,
  xticklabel=\ifthenelse{\equal{\tick}{dummy}}{\textcolor{red}{\tick}}{\tick}]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (foo,2)
    (bar,4)
    (dummy,3)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to use `etoolbox`, you'll have to use `\ifdefstring{<macro>}{<string>}`, which compares the content of a macro to a string.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  symbolic x coords={foo,bar,dummy},
  xtick=data,
  xticklabel=\ifdefstring{\tick}{dummy}{\textcolor{red}{\tick}}{\tick}]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (foo,2)
    (bar,4)
    (dummy,3)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works. But out of curiosity, how would a solution using `etoolbox` look like, in particular in the light of [Why is the ifthen package obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete)

Comment: @Andreas: I've edited my answer to show how to do it with `etoolbox`.