# Algorithmicx -- How to use latex maths delimiters

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, algorithmicx

Today, I decided to migrate from using TeX [`$..$`] to LaTeX [`\(..\)`] delimiters for inline maths, and, as usual, fell off the cliff of my somewhat precarious understanding of TeXian gastroenterology, in the middle of an `algpseudocode` environment.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Trigger Dispatching Scheduler}{}
\State \Call{MqOpen}{$\aleph$}
\State \Call{MqOpen}{\(\aleph\)\relax}
%\State \Call{MqOpen}{\(\aleph\)} % <== This one fails
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Uncommenting the %-line causes it to fail (PdfLaTeX *and* XeLaTeX) with:

```
! Argument of \) has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 \State \Call{MqOpen}{\(\aleph\)}
                                      % <== This one fails
```

What, if anything, am I doing wrong? If anyone could explain in fairly simple terms what's going on here, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the word *'fragile'* (which precisely describes my understanding of these things)

Comment: I think so (based on [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13882/5764)) and [`algorithmicx`(http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) uses [`ifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) to condition on many levels. For example, using `\State \Call{MqOpen}{\protect\(\aleph\protect\)}` works. Not exactly sure why `\relax` makes it work though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I give an answer below saying it's a bug in `ifthen` package, but I think I'm going to reclassify it as a *feature*.

In unmodified LaTeX2e `\(` \nd `\)` are *fragile* commands and as such they should be preceded by `\protect` if used in a moving argument (as the argument of `\equal`).

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\protect\(a\protect\)}{\protect\(a\protect\)}}{\typeout Y}{\typeout N}
```

does work as intended.

If you load the `fixltx2e` package part of the core base distribution then `\(` and `\)` are made *robust* so you (and even I) might have expected that `\protect` is not necessary. However the due to the way `\ifthenelse` overloads the `\( \)` syntax to be a  boolean logic parenthesis rather than math start, `\(` is made fragile again. The "fix" below locally gives `\(\)` robust definitions however due to the "interesting" expansion order implemented in `ifthenelse` This local redefinition applies to the entire predicate not just the arguments to `\equal` and so the "fix" is entirely wrong as it removes the `ifthenelse` definition of `\(\)` entirely.

Sorry (if you want to take away the green tick I'd understand:-) but unless sleeping on it gives me a better idea, or another contributor has a better idea, I think the only thing I can do is more clearly document in `ifthen` that if you use the `ifthen` syntax commands (`\(\)\or\and\isodd` etc inside an `\equals` test, then you need to `\protect` them.

---

Sorry it's a bug.

`\ifthenelse` uses delimiters `\(` and `\)` to brackets boolean expressions. These are not made safe in the strings used by `ifthenelse` `\equal` test. The following inserts a local definition to make things safer,

```
 \let\(\relax\let\)\relax
```

without this line you get the same error shown in your MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter

\long\def\ifthenelse#1{%
  \toks@{#1}%
  \TE@repl\or\TE@or
  \TE@repl\and\TE@and
  \TE@repl\not\TE@neg
  \TE@repl\OR\TE@or
  \TE@repl\AND\TE@and
  \TE@repl\NOT\TE@neg
    \begingroup
        \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
        \def\@setref##1##2##3{%
         \ifx##1\relax\z@\else\expandafter##2##1\fi}%
        \def\value##1{\the\csname c@##1\endcsname}%
        \let\equal\TE@equal \let\(\TE@lparen \let\)\TE@rparen
        \let\isodd\TE@odd \let\lengthtest\TE@length
        \let\isundefined\TE@undef
        \begingroup
          \let\@tempa\relax\let\@tempb\relax
          \let\(\relax\let\)\relax
          \xdef\@gtempa{\expandafter\TE@eval\the\toks@\TE@endeval}%
        \endgroup
        \@gtempa
        \expandafter\endgroup\ifTE@val
          \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
          \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi}

\makeatother


\ifthenelse{\equal{a}{a}}{\typeout Y}{\typeout N}
\ifthenelse{\equal{a}{b}}{\typeout Y}{\typeout N}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\(a\)}{\(a\)}}{\typeout Y}{\typeout N}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\(a\)}{\(b\)}}{\typeout Y}{\typeout N}


\stop


This produces

Y
N
Y
N
 )
No pages of output.
```

on the terminal showing the tests worked.

Comment: Thanks, David. What do you think is the best way of "implementing" this?: (a) make a patched local copy of ifthen.sty, or (b) put your code into a local `fixifthen.sty` and then `\usepackage{fixifthen}`?

Comment: actually I'm not sure that's quite the right fix (I may have broken the ifthen use of `\(` I need to make a couple of test cases. As it's clearly a bug I would just patch ifthen.sty locally (putting some note in the \ProvidesPackage line to note it is modified) that way the document doesn't need changing once the main distribution gets fixed.