# Use alternate cite keys depending on document version

Tags: natbib, conditionals

My biggest enemy is the page limit. I use short versions of my BibTeX entries in order to keep the list of references short. I now have a situation where I include the file in the journal article and also in a book. I want to use the long reference in the book and the short in the journal. I defined a boolean that is set to true if we are in the journal tex files and then defined a command that is supposed to return the short or long key depending on the value of the boolean. But somehow this does not work. Is there a way to reach my goals?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\provideboolean{jl}
\setboolean{jl}{true}


% cite alternate between the long and short citation key
\newcommand{\citekeyshortlong}[2]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{jl}}{#1}{#2}}


\begin{document}

\citet[\page 48]{\citekeyshortlong{XY-short}{XY-long}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `etoolbox` (which I prefer as its syntax seems simpler to me) you should use a toggle: `\newtoggle{jl}\toggletrue{jl}`, and then `\newcommand{\citekeyshortlong}[2]{\iftoggle{jl}{#1}{#2}}`.

Comment: `\ifthenelse` is not expandable, whereas `\iftoggle` from `etoolbox` is, hence why Peter's suggestion works and yours does not. See eg [Why is the ifthen package obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/17427)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend putting the conditional outermost, so defining the `\citekeyshortlong` conditionally:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{jl}
\toggletrue{jl} %% Use short refs

\iftoggle{jl}{%
     \newcommand{\citekeyshortlong}[2]{#1}}{%
     \newcommand{\citekeyshortlong}[2]{#2}}
```

(substituting etoolbox for ifthenelse as recommended by Peter Grill - though this will work with ifthenelse).