# Making a "For Loop"

Tags: macros, conditionals

I am trying to make a "for loop" that will iterate the variable reaches 1.
However, none of the "for loops" I have found in the Internet works.

These files will be distributed to other people and thus it would help if we only stick to the default packages. In this case, I'm using the `ifthen` package.

```
\newcommand{\displayauthors}[1]
{
\newcounter{blargh}
\setcounter{blargh}{#1}
\ifthenelse{#1 = 0}{

}{
\the\value{blargh}
\displayauthors{\value{blargh}}
}
```

This command is error-free.
However, when I run

```
\displayauthors{2}
```

LaTeX complains that

```
Command \c@blargh already defined.
```

What is causing this and how do I fix this?

Comment: Not related to your specific problem but you and your colleagues who are working on the same files might be interested to read: [Why is the ifthen package obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following solution doesn't need any package nor any counter, is much faster, resolves tail recursion, is expandable, and deals with the trailing/last comma (,).

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\displayauthors#1{%
  \ifnum#1>0 #1\ifnum\numexpr#1-1>0, \fi
    \expandafter\displayauthors\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1-1\expandafter}%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\displayauthors{10}

\edef\x{\displayauthors{10}}\x
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 that's what I'd do, but I thought I'd keep my answer closer to the MWE to show what was wrong with the original code, rather than just replace all of it. Good to show this alternative though.

Comment: Hey thanks. That seems to work. May I know the logic behind this? I don't know what \displayauthors#1 does, among other things. Does anyone have a good source I can read?

Comment: "The Tex Book" by D.E. Knuth.

Answer (score 16):

Move

```
\newcounter{blargh}
```

out of the macro body and place it before the definition. You do not want to allocate a new register on each use, each loop should use the same register which is allocated once at the start.

---

Also you need to decrement the counter and a few `%` at ends of lines

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{blargh}

\newcommand{\displayauthors}[1]
{%
\setcounter{blargh}{#1}%
\ifthenelse{#1 = 0}{%
}{%
\theblargh, %
\addtocounter{blargh}{-1}%
\displayauthors{\value{blargh}}%
}}

\begin{document}

\displayauthors{10}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You mention not finding any success with a for loop. Here's one option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido
\newcommand{\displaynums}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<0\else\multido{\i=#1+-1}{#1}{\i\ }\unskip\fi}
\begin{document}
4: \displaynums{4}\par
12: \displaynums{12}\par
1: \displaynums{1}\par
0: \displaynums{0}\par
-7: \displaynums{-7}
\end{document}
```

[`multido`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido) provides an iterative/sequential interface to variables:

```
\multido{<var>=<start>+<increment>}{<times>}{<stuff>}
```

There is some difference between real/integer usage. See the [`multido`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/multido/multido-doc.pdf) for more information.