# Is "conditionals" name of package?

Tags: macros, conditionals, miktex

In some package I have seen construct like this one:

```
\if\blank{\myMacro}%
  %do something
\else
  %do something else
\fi
```

I like it and I want to use it to test if call to a macro has empty result. I have tried it in my code and I have found out that the `\blank` macro does not work until I add `\usepackage{conditionals}` to preamble.

Now here is the problem: I have tried to find documentation to package "conditionals" but there seems to be no such package installed (nor available) on my MiKTeX distribution. I have tried search included in MiKTeX package manager but did not find it. Why is that? Where do I find documentation of that package?

*Side note:* I was looking for the documentation because I wanted find opposite macro something like `\notblank`

Comment: A search of my system reveals that the file `conditionals.sty`  is part of the `songbook` package. However, there is no documentation with the latter about conditionals. I'd therefore suggest you want to look at something like `etoolbox`: perhaps you could focus the question on the test you need rather than what seems to be an obscure support package.

Comment: Could this be what you are looking for?: http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/ifthen.pdf

Comment: @Dave Many of us would take the line discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866 that there are more powerful alternatives to `ifthen`.

Comment: `\if\blank{\myMacro}` is most definitively wrong. This is not how the `\if` primitive works. I think you means some `\ifblank` macro instead.

Comment: @MartinScharrer could be that `\blank{\myMacro}` expands to `01` or `11` depending on whether `\myMacro` is `blank` or not... (or rather the contrary)

Comment: @jfbu: You are right, this way it would work with `\if`, and even make sense if you want to work with `\if.. \else  \fi` instead with a `\@if..{..}{..}` construct.

Comment: @MartinScharrer it's by Donald Arseneau so chances are it's right:-)

Comment: @Martin Scharrer It is that correct `\if\blank{...}` is the syntax used and I also expect it to expand to either `01` or `11`. And the reason I like it is really the one you mentioned: I prefer to work with `\if.. \else \fi` rather then `\@if..{..}{..}`. I have programming background so that fits me better. My problem is that that blank command seems not to work with macros. So while `\if\blank{#1}` works correctly, `\if\blank{\myEmpty}` does not.

Comment: @Joseph Wright I did not know that it is obscure suppport package at the first place... I do not want to use it if that is the case. I will probably just accept the only answer and ask another, better formulated question.

Answer (score 10):

The macros in the `conditionals` package are by Donald Arsenau and according to the commentary in the package they are public domain.

So here they are:

```
{\catcode`\!=8 % funny catcode so ! will be a delimiter
 \catcode`\Q=3 % funny catcode so Q will be a delimiter
\long\gdef\given#1{88\fi\Ifbl@nk#1QQQ\empty!}
\long\gdef\blank#1{88\fi\Ifbl@nk#1QQ..!}% if null or spaces
\long\gdef\nil#1{\IfN@Ught#1* {#1}!}% if null
\long\gdef\IfN@Ught#1 #2!{\blank{#2}}
\long\gdef\Ifbl@nk#1#2Q#3!{\ifx#3}% same as above
}
```

Surround the code by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` if you want to use them in your document.

Let's see what happens when `\if\blank{<tokens>}<TRUE>\else<FALSE>\fi` is expanded, concentrating on the `\if\blank{<tokens>}` part. Usually `<tokens>` will be the argument to a macro.

One has to know that `\if` continues expansion until it finds two unexpandable tokens after it, of which it compares the character code. So the first expansion is

```
\if88\fi\Ifbl@nk<tokens>QQ..!
```

and `\if` compares `8` with `8`; the `\fi` closes the conditional which does nothing at all! It's just there to allow the construction to be nested with other conditionals. Now TeX finds

```
\Ifbl@nk<tokens>QQ..!
```

If `<tokens>` consists only of (zero or more) spaces, the search for the first (undelimited) argument to `\Ifbl@nk` will bypass them. In this case argument `#1` will be `Q`<sub>3</sub> (the subscript denotes the funny category code), argument `#2` will be empty and argument `#3` will be `..`, so finally we'll have

```
\ifx..<TRUE>\else<FALSE>\fi
```

which will choose the true branch. Suppose now that in `<tokens>` there is a non space token. The first such token (or braced group) will become the first argument to `\Ifbl@nk`, while the rest will be argument `#2`. So anything up to `!`<sub>8</sub> will be argument `#3`, that is `Q..` so TeX will see

```
\ifx Q..<TRUE>\else<FALSE>\fi
```

and the comparison is between `Q`<sub>3</sub> and `.`<sub>12</sub> which are different, so the trailing period will vanish with the ignored true branch and the false branch will be followed.

Note that no expansion of `<tokens>` takes place; this list of tokens disappears completely.

With `\if\given{<tokens>}`, after the same `\if88\fi` that disappears, TeX finds

```
\Ifbl@nk<tokens>QQQ\empty!
```

Again, if `<tokens>` consists of (zero or more) spaces, these will be bypassed and argument `#1` will be `Q`, argument `#2` will be empty and argument `#3` will be `Q\empty`; so TeX will see

```
\ifx Q\empty<TRUE>\else<FALSE>\fi
```

thus following the false branch. If some non blank token appears in `<tokens>` the first one (or the first braced group) will be `#1`, the rest will be `#2` and `#3` will be `QQ\empty`. In this case TeX will see

```
\ifx QQ\empty<TRUE>\else<FALSE>\fi
```

so `\empty` starts the true branch, but its expansion is empty and is (almost) irrelevant.

Last, `\if\nil{<tokens>}`. After `\if88\fi` we get

```
\IfN@Ught<tokens>* {<tokens>}!
```

Now leading blank tokens in `<tokens>` will *not* be bypassed, because the first argument to `\IfN@Ught` is delimited by a space. Everything after a leading space will become `#2` and at least `*` is there, so `\blank{#2}` will return false. If the first token in `<tokens>` is not a space, at least `{<tokens>}` will become part of `#2`, so that `\blank{#2}` will return false as well.

Thus the only way `\if\nil{<tokens>}` can return true is that `<tokens>` is really empty (no tokens at all).

Very clever macros indeed!

### Alternative 1

Use `etoolbox` that provides

```
\ifstrempty{<tokens>}{<true>}{<false>}
\ifblank{<tokens>}{<true>}{<false>}
\notblank{<tokens>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

that are equivalent to

```
\if\nil{<tokens>}
\if\blank{<tokens>}
\if\given{<tokens>}
```

respectively, but with a different syntax (no `\else` and `\fi`). The footnote to the documentation in `etoolbox` says that the macros are based on code by Donald Arsenau, which quite probably is the same as in `conditionals.sty`.

### Alternative 2

In LaTeX3 there are similar constructs:

```
\tl_if_empty:nTF {<tokens>}{<TRUE>}{<FALSE>}
```

is the same as `\if\nil{<tokens>}`, while

```
\tl_if_blank:nTF {<tokens>}{<TRUE>}{<FALSE>}
```

is the same as `\if\blank{<tokens>}`. Of course the syntax is similar to the one in `etoolbox`. There's actually no need for an analogous to `\if\given{<tokens>}`.

Answer (score 4):

The conditionals package does in fact provide the opposite of blank:

```
 \if\blank{ } --- checks if parameter is blank (Spaces count as blank)
 \if\given{ } --- checks if parameter is not blank: like \if\blank{}...\else
 \if\nil{ }   --- checks if parameter is null (spaces are NOT null)
```

If you look in the log file of a document using `\usepackage{conditionals}` you will see the full path to the file. Each time TeX opens a file it writes a `(` to the log file followed by the path to the file opened,and it writes a `)` to the log file once it has finished reading the file.