# How to detect that some macro expands to empty string or spaces only?

Tags: macros, conditionals, strings

I need to check several macros and do some actions only if their expansion is not empty nor space only.

In pseudo code I would look like this

```
\if\macroToBeTested
    \doSomething
    \doSomethingElse
\fi
```

macros `\doSomething` and `\doSomethingElse` should only execute if `\macroToBeTested` expands to something that contains at least one character which is not space.

How can I implement that? I prefer using something like this

```
\if\test{\macroToBeTested}%
  \doSomething%
  \doSomethingElse%
\fi
```

rather then anything like this

```
\test{\macroToBeTested}{%
  \doSomething%
  \doSomethingElse%
}
```

---

### EDIT

Here is example (pseudocode)

```
\newcommand{\macroToBeTested}{   }%
Hello%
\if\test{\macro}%
  World!%
\fi
```

This would print only "Hello", while this

```
\newcommand{\macroToBeTested}{  s }%
Hello%
\if\test{\macro}%
  World!%
\fi
```

should print "Hello World!".

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately Donald Arsenau's `\given` macro only works with arguments, it does not work correctly if argument of `\given` is another macro. Your other code in answerhttp://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94931/3442 uses the other syntax (not `\if...\else...\fi`)

Comment: Related Question: [Proper way to detect empty/blank text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44919/proper-way-to-detect-empty-blank-text).

Answer (score 7):

Just use the code by D. Arsenau mentioned in [Is "conditionals" name of package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94919/is-conditionals-name-of-package) with an additional macro:

```
\makeatletter
{\catcode`\!=8 % funny catcode so ! will be a delimiter
 \catcode`\Q=3 % funny catcode so Q will be a delimiter
\long\gdef\given#1{88\fi\Ifbl@nk#1QQQ\empty!}
\long\gdef\blank#1{88\fi\Ifbl@nk#1QQ..!}% if null or spaces
\long\gdef\nil#1{\IfN@Ught#1* {#1}!}% if null
\long\gdef\IfN@Ught#1 #2!{\blank{#2}}
\long\gdef\Ifbl@nk#1#2Q#3!{\ifx#3}% same as above
}
\makeatother
\def\expblank{\expandafter\blank\expandafter} % additional macro
```

Now

```
\if\expblank{\mymacro}%
  <code if \mymacro expands only to zero or more spaces>%
\else
  <code if \mymacro expansion contains non space tokens>%
\fi
```

will do.

You can define similarly `\expnil` and `\expgiven`.

### Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
{\catcode`\!=8 % funny catcode so ! will be a delimiter
 \catcode`\Q=3 % funny catcode so Q will be a delimiter
\long\gdef\given#1{88\fi\Ifbl@nk#1QQQ\empty!}
\long\gdef\blank#1{88\fi\Ifbl@nk#1QQ..!}% if null or spaces
\long\gdef\nil#1{\IfN@Ught#1* {#1}!}% if null
\long\gdef\IfN@Ught#1 #2!{\blank{#2}}
\long\gdef\Ifbl@nk#1#2Q#3!{\ifx#3}% same as above
}
\makeatother
\def\expblank{\expandafter\blank\expandafter}
\def\expgiven{\expandafter\given\expandafter}
\def\expnil{\expandafter\nil\expandafter}

\def\foo{ }
\def\bar{}
\def\baz{\bar}

\if\expgiven{\foo}
  \typeout{NOT BLANK}
\else
  \typeout{BLANK}
\fi

\if\expblank{\foo}
  \typeout{BLANK}
\else
  \typeout{NOT BLANK}
\fi

\if\expblank{\bar}
  \typeout{BLANK}
\else
  \typeout{NOT BLANK}
\fi

\if\expblank{\baz}
  \typeout{BLANK}
\else
  \typeout{NOT BLANK}
\fi
```

The log shows

```
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
NOT BLANK
```

Comment: That `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are necessary there? What is their function?

Comment: You have to use `\expgiven` as defined in the complete example. For `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: @egreg If e-TeX is available, using the `\detokenize` approach would be more robust (can't get caught out by an odd `Q`).

Comment: @JosephWright You mean changing `\fi\Ifbl@nk#1` into `\fi\expandafter\Ifbl@nk\detokenize{#1}`? Indeed it would be safer.