# Getting rid of one `\scriptspace` in a double sub/superscript

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

When constructing a superscript box or a subscript box, TeX will automatically append a kern of `\scriptspace` to the end of that hbox. And if you write a double subscript, say, `$A_{i_k}$`, then there will be two `\scriptspace`s, which creates too much white space on the right.

How can you get rid of just one `\scriptspace`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
For $i_1$, $i_2$,~$\ldots$, and~$i_k$, we have
\[
P(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_k})
=P(A_{i_1}) P(A_{i_2}) \cdots P(A_{i_k}).
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\dsub}[2]{_{#1_{#2}}\hspace*{-1\scriptspace}}` used with `A\dsub{i}{1}` maybe? (Though that might be annoying.)

Comment: @frabjous This surely is one way to go. But the backing up negative space should really go *inside* one of scripts. The first reason is somewhat obvious: Let’s say you write `$A\dsub{i}{1}^c$` for the complement of `$A\dsub{i}{1}$`. You certainly would want the `^c` to attach to the `A` instead of the negative space, wouldn’t you? The second reason is somewhat philosophical: It’s “logically more natural” to put the negative space inside (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/616371).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using LuaTeX then you can set script-space values individually for all math styles using the `\Umathspaceafterscript` primitive. Note, that the math style of the nucleus is relevant. Example: `$a_{b_c}$` adds `\Umathspaceafterscript\textstyle` after `b_c` and `\Umathspaceafterscript\crampedscriptstyle` after `c`. The resulting space is the sum of these two.

You can try following setting:

```
\Umathspaceafterscript\displaystyle=.5pt
\Umathspaceafterscript\crampeddisplaystyle=.5pt
\Umathspaceafterscript\textstyle=.5pt
\Umathspaceafterscript\crampedtextstyle=.5pt
\Umathspaceafterscript\scriptstyle=0pt
\Umathspaceafterscript\crampedscriptstyle=0pt
\Umathspaceafterscript\scriptscriptstyle=0pt
\Umathspaceafterscript\crampedscriptscriptstyle=0pt
```

Comment: Xe(La)TeX users crying internally. More seriously though, this is still not smart enough to understand context (I guess?). Say, we want to write multi-index object, `$A_{i_1 j_1 k_1}$` (I know it’d be better to switch to a parenthesized expression, but this is sort of “necessary evil”). Then really the `\scriptspace`s in `i_1` and `j_1` should stay. My question would be unchanged though: in this case, there are 4 `\scriptspace`s, and I still want to get rid of just one, namely, the one from the `k_1`.